# How to animate a NSLayoutConstraint within a CAAnimationGroup

Tags: ios, ios6, core-animation, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I had for example this in pre-autolayout times which was added to a CAAnimationGroup.

```
CABasicAnimation *resizeAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds.size"];
[resizeAnimation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(10.0f, 10.0f)]];
resizeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
resizeAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
```

Under autolayout I assume that now I will need to change the Constant property of my Constraints on the object.

So could you please help me to understand how to prepare the animation of a constraint.

**EDIT** In Best Practices Mastering Auto Layout - at around 30m he does this on OSX with NSAnimationContext - he does not talk about iOS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I animate constraint changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622424/how-do-i-animate-constraint-changes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best answer I can come up with is you cannot do this. You either need to animate a layer or use the UiView animation methods.