# UISegementedControl reverts back to original frame after touch

Tags: ios, ios7, uisegmentedcontrol, uiviewanimation

Every time I click on my UISegementedControl it snaps back to its original frame. I can see it barely through my translucent toolbar.
I have a UIViewController with a UITableView, and UIToolBar like this: 
[image: my view controller]

There is a UISegmentedControl hidden just below the table view, behind the toolbar: 
[image: storyboard layout setup]

The Filter button calls the 'onFilterButtonPressed' method

```
- (IBAction)onFilterButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if(self.filterBar.hidden){
        [self showFilterBar];
    } else {
        [self hideFilterBar];
    }
}

- (void)hideFilterBar
{
    CGRect filterBarFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height+(self.filterBar.frame.size.height+1), self.filterBar.frame.size.width, self.filterBar.frame.size.height);
    CGRect tableViewFrame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y,self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height+(self.filterBar.frame.size.height+1));

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [self.filterBar setFrame:filterBarFrame];
        [self.tableView setFrame:tableViewFrame];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.filterBar.hidden = YES;
    }];
}

- (void)showFilterBar
{
    CGRect filterBarFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-(self.filterBar.frame.size.height+1), self.filterBar.frame.size.width, self.filterBar.frame.size.height);
    CGRect tableViewFrame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y,self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height-(self.filterBar.frame.size.height+1));

    self.filterBar.hidden = NO;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [self.tableView setFrame:tableViewFrame];
        [self.filterBar setFrame:filterBarFrame];
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of auto layout. With that turned on (which it is by default), you should do any positioning or resizing of views by modifying constraints, not setting frames.

Comment: Thanks, Apple's docs about animation don't say anything about animating constrains, but do about setting frames. I found this with your suggestion [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622424/how-do-i-animate-constraint-changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622424/how-do-i-animate-constraint-changes) and that worked.