# iOS 7 back swipe gesture and keyboard dismissal

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uikeyboard

I have a standard `UINavigationViewController` with a standard `UIInteractivePopGestureRecognizer` for iOS 7. I also have these well known and widely-used methods:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

They work like this:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification{
    CGFloat keyboardSlideDuration = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey: UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue];

    UIViewAnimationOptions keyboardAnimationCurve = [[notification userInfo][UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue]<<16;

    if (keyboardIsUp || isAnimating) return;

    isAnimating = YES;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:keyboardSlideDuration delay:0 options:(keyboardAnimationCurve | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState) animations:^{
        _topConstraint.constant -= kTopConstraintR4Ratio;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        keyboardIsUp = YES;
        isAnimating = NO;
    }];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification{

    CGFloat keyboardSlideDuration = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey: UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue];

    UIViewAnimationOptions keyboardAnimationCurve = [[notification userInfo][UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue]<<16;

    if (isAnimating) return;

    isAnimating = YES;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:keyboardSlideDuration delay:0 options:(keyboardAnimationCurve | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState) animations:^{
        _topConstraint.constant = topConstraintOriginalValue;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        keyboardIsUp = NO;
        isAnimating = NO;
    }];
}
```

The thing is that `UIView animateWithDuration` is triggered without any respect to duration when I swipe the view back with a gesture. The whole view turns into a mess - it animates slowly when I pop the view, but when the gesture isn't finished - the view jumps up.

It looks like this:

[image]

How do I get rid of this strange behavior? **I don't want** the view to move during the transition and I want it to stay still.

**EDIT**:

You can download the sample project using the link here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/034lfy49ru4pelf/SampleProject.zip

Comment: To be honest I think it's cooler that it moves like that.

Comment: @TonyD It might be, but it certainly **not** what I want and it looks more like a bug.

Comment: I'm wondering, if you slide all the way to the right, will the keyboard be dismissed?

Comment: @TonyD, yes of course

Comment: Can you post a sample project, I would like to take a look.

Comment: @LeoNatan - check it out - https://www.dropbox.com/s/034lfy49ru4pelf/SampleProject.zip

Comment: Have you tried unsubscribing from keyboard notifications in `-viewWillDisappear:` and subscribing back in `-viewDidAppear:`?

Comment: @NikolayKasyanov tried it and it just doesn't work very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy hack:

```
BOOL needAdjustContstrain;
```

Set `needAdjustContstrain` to `YES` in `keyboardWillShow:`

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if (needAdjustContstrain) {
         _topContstraint.constant -=40;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that looks like it, as simple as it gets. Working on a sample project. I'll do some testing and report back with the results. Need to implement it on 4-5 VCs and see.

Comment: It seems to be buggy.. Check keyboard notification sequence when interactivePopGestureRecognizer in action

Comment: It will always call `keyboardWillHide` first and probably `keyboardWillShow` next

Comment: Yes, I think therefor my hack works only for first gesture, need to be tuned

Comment: Confirmed, the 2nd and subsequent gestures break all the harmony.

Comment: So when do we put the `BOOL` to `NO`, then? E.G. I need to hide the keyboard on the view and I don't want it to animate when I pop it.

Comment: There is, if I need to hide the keyboard and when I do, it will still be YES, therefore, the view will animate as if there's a keyboard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58167/discussion-between-nucleus-and-sergiusgee).

Answer (score -2):

you need to call the layoutIfneeded method before the animation block . Check out the code below :

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification{

CGFloat keyboardSlideDuration = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey: UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue];

UIViewAnimationOptions keyboardAnimationCurve = [[notification userInfo][UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue]<<16;

if (isAnimating) return;

isAnimating = YES;

[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
[UIView animateWithDuration:keyboardSlideDuration delay:0 options:(keyboardAnimationCurve | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState) animations:^{
    _topContstraint.constant = 89;
  //
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    keyboardIsUp = NO;
    isAnimating = NO;
}];}
```

Please check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622424/how-do-i-animate-constraint-changes)

Comment: Not performing layout will not perform the animation correctly in other places of the code, where animation is needed.

Comment: Absolutely not a credible answer - this way the animation is not being performed correctly, just like @LeoNatan said.

Comment: That's not going to work and has nothing to do to the UIInteractivePopGesture

Comment: @SergiusGee i have tested the above code and its working fine.

Comment: @sigkill What's working fine? The animation is broken, the view still moves with the gesture recognizer. How on earth do you expect to break the `UIView` animation cycle and expect it to work?

Comment: @sigkill Jesus, even the link you pointed out to says: 
`You need to call layoutIfNeeded within the animation block.` Do you even look what you post? Within != before.