# Prevent cell content from "jumping" when applying constraint

Tags: swift, uikit, uicollectionviewcell, nslayoutconstraint, uistackview

I have a subclassed UICollectionViewCell and I want it to expand when tapped.

To achieve this, I put the title into a view ("titleStack") and the body into a separate view ("bodyStack"), and then put both of them into a container UIStackView ("mainStack"). I then constrain the contentView of the cell to the leading, trailing, and top edges of **mainStack**.

When the cell is selected, a constraint is applied that sets the bottom of the contentView's constraint to be the bottom of **bodyStack**. When it's unselected, I remove that constraint and instead apply one that sets the contentView's bottom constraint equal to **titleStack's** bottom constraint.

For the most part this works well, but when deselecting, there's this little jump, as you can see in this video:

[image]

What I would like is for **titleStack** to stay pinned to the top while the cell animates the shrinking portion, but it appears to jump to the bottom, giving it a sort of glitchy look. I'm wondering how I can change this.

I've pasted the relevant code below:

```
private func setUp() {
    backgroundColor = .systemGray6
    clipsToBounds = true
    layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius

    setUpMainStack()
    setUpConstraints()
    updateAppearance()
}

private func setUpMainStack() {
    
    contentView.constrain(mainStack, using: .edges, padding: 5, except: [.bottom])
    mainStack.add([titleStack, bodyStack])
    
    bodyStack.add([countryLabel, foundedLabel, codeLabel, nationalLabel])
}

private func setUpConstraints() {
    titleStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    
    closedConstraint =
        titleStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
    closedConstraint?.priority = .defaultLow // use low priority so stack stays pinned to top of cell
    
    openConstraint =
        bodyStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
    openConstraint?.priority = .defaultLow
}

/// Updates the views to reflect changes in selection
private func updateAppearance() {

    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.closedConstraint?.isActive = !self.isSelected
        self.openConstraint?.isActive = self.isSelected
    }
}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Instead of setting the constraints active/inactive, can you try animating the constraint values like this?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25650669/4490923

Comment: That didn't quite work in my case, but it led me down the right path so thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by simply showing and hiding my "bodyStack" as well as using "layoutIfNeeded." I removed closedConstraint and openConstraint and just gave it a normal bottom constraint.

The relevant code:

```
func updateAppearance() {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            
            self.bodyStack.isHidden = !self.isSelected
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```