# Move textfield when keyboard appears swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, keyboard, uitextfield

I'm using Swift for programing with iOS and I'm using this code to move the `UITextField`, but it does not work. I call the function `keyboardWillShow` correctly, but the textfield doesn't move. I'm using autolayout.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
}

deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self);
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        //let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)

        var frame = self.ChatField.frame
        frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y - keyboardSize.height + 167
        self.chatField.frame = frame
        println("asdasd")
    }
}
```

Comment: Walkthrough guide with Project files: https://www.codebeaulieu.com/43/Triggering-NSNotificationCenter-notifications-from-the-UI

Comment: Perhaps deinit and viewDidLoad are not balanced.

Comment: Based on both Apple's docs and personal experience. 
Here's my git repo using UIScrollView to move TF: https://github.com/29satnam/MoveTextFieldWhenKeyboardAppearsSwift

Answer (score 340, accepted):

There are a couple of improvements to be made on the existing answers.

Firstly the **UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification** is probably the best notification as it handles changes that aren't just show/hide but changes due to keyboard changes (language, using 3rd party keyboards etc.) and rotations too (but note comment below indicating the keyboard will hide should also be handled to support hardware keyboard connection).

Secondly the animation parameters can be pulled from the notification to ensure that animations are properly together.

There are probably options to clean up this code a bit more especially if you are comfortable with force unwrapping the dictionary code.

```
 class MyViewController: UIViewController {

   // This constraint ties an element at zero points from the bottom layout guide
   @IBOutlet var keyboardHeightLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
 
   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
       selector: #selector(self.keyboardNotification(notification:)),
       name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification,
       object: nil)
   }
 
   deinit {
     NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
   }
 
   @objc func keyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
     guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }

     let endFrame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
     let endFrameY = endFrame?.origin.y ?? 0
     let duration:TimeInterval = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0
     let animationCurveRawNSN = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
     let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.uintValue ?? UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut.rawValue
     let animationCurve:UIView.AnimationOptions = UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)

     if endFrameY >= UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height {
       self.keyboardHeightLayoutConstraint?.constant = 0.0
     } else {
       self.keyboardHeightLayoutConstraint?.constant = endFrame?.size.height ?? 0.0
     }

     UIView.animate(
       withDuration: duration,
       delay: TimeInterval(0),
       options: animationCurve,
       animations: { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() },
       completion: nil)
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi @joseph-lord, I think the `animateWithDuration` is actually doing nothing. Try changing the duration to something like `10.0` seconds, or even just commenting out the whole animation call, and just running `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` instead. For me, it seems to be overridden by the keyboard's own animation. Maybe iOS calls `commitAnimation` after calling the keyboard notification.

Comment: @nathan.f77 Are you changing a `keyboardHeightLayoutConstraint` that has been set up between the bottom thing that you want to animate and the bottom layout guide? That line is key and the constraint should not be `nil`. The `self.view.layoutIfNeeded` in the animation block should apply the updated constraint.

Comment: @JosephLord nice. but I found this doesn't work when keyboard is hiding because `endFrame?.size.height` is not nil. I got the end frame as `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 1024}, {768, 264}}";`. Ran on iOS 8.3 iPad Simulator, Portrait. Xcode6.3 beta4.

Comment: @Hlung If that is the endframe on hiding it sounds like the keyboard animated offscreen but didn't actually shrink. You may need to get the window size to know for sure that 1024 is the bottom of the screen. It would then need the constraint constant set to screenheight - endFrame.origin.y.

Comment: if the keyboard doesn't hide, try using this code
if endFrame?.origin.y >= UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height {
                self.keyboardHeightLayoutConstraint?.constant = 0.0
            } else {
                   self.keyboardHeightLayoutConstraint?.constant = endFrame.size.height
            }

Comment: When the keyboard is dismissed it does not seem to reset the view. This is probably just an overall error with my constraints but yeah :S

Comment: keyBoardHeightLayoutConstraint is a constraint defined in InterfaceBuilder constraining the bottom of the view that you want to move/shrink to the bottom layout guide or the bottom of the main view for the viewcontroller. The constant is initially set to zero and will be adjusted to make room for the keyboard when the keyboard appears or changes size.

Comment: Works best for me so far.  I suggest to read out the constraint's initial constant in case it's not zero:

var keyboardHeightLayoutConstraintConstant: CGFloat? = 0
...
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
 self.keyboardHeightLayoutConstraintConstant = self.keyboardHeightLayoutConstraint?.constant
}
...
func keyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
....
 self.keyboardHeightLayoutConstraint?.constant = endFrame?.size.height ?? 0.0
 self.keyboardHeightLayoutConstraint?.constant += keyboardHeightLayoutConstraintConstant!

Comment: I didn't read the "PLEASE NOTE" at the bottom and just realised that @Gabox solved my issue that the keyboard was simply translated rather than shrunk!! Thanks.

Comment: the constrain dont go to zero after keyboard dismissed

Comment: for some reason the view will animate with the keyboard when its dismissed, but the animation is skipped when it appears...  even thought its the same code handling both, quite strange. if i use the UIKeyboard**Did**ChangeFrameNotification it works fine though, but then the animation is delayed because the keyboard has to finish its animation first

Comment: ok nevermind, it was just the simulator being silly, it works fine on device

Comment: That works like a charm... Thanks alot! But There's a slight problem on iPad when the keyboard is split or detached... Any good practice to handle these two special cases?

Comment: @Fonix I'm getting the issue you're talking about with the keyboard not animating on appearance, yet still working on disappearance with iOS 10 now. It was working fine before I updated to iOS 10 too. Is it still working fine on your device with the new upgrade?

Comment: Hi, this works perfectly! it was the answer i was looking for, but when i tab outside for keyboard to dissapear, the view moves lower. what can i do?

Comment: Note that `.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame` doesn't fire when a hardware keyboard is connected, even though the iOS keyboard disappears. You need to observe `.UIKeyboardWillHide` as well to catch that edge case.

Comment: @jamesk Good catch, do you have a proposed edit? Is it as simple as adding the extra observer or does the handling code need updating too? I've not got time to experiment at the moment.

Comment: @Sulthan works okay.. My issue is that is getting a bit higher than the keybaord. is there any way we can fix this?

Comment: Code didnt work for me so i just removed if/else and replaced with `self.<enterbuttonname>.frame.origin.y = endFrameY - self.<enterbuttonname>.frame.height`

Comment: There are several CocoaPods that provide robust keyboard avoiding solutions. I recommend https://github.com/IdleHandsApps/IHKeyboardAvoiding, but of course I do, I wrote it :)

Comment: @Fraser I just couldn't get your CocoaPods working, how to import your module? Please improve the installation part of README.

Comment: @giovannipds `import IHKeyboardAvoiding` is all you need. Raise an issue on Github if you're still having issues

Comment: @Fraser thanks for answering, pretty sure I've tried that. It was probably an Xcode delay or something. Anyway, I dealt with it in other way.

Comment: doesn't work for Swift 4 you should edit the answer or don't mark it as a solution for Swift 4.x

Comment: @JosephLord can you explain to me, why not used input accessory view ??

Comment: @a.masri The intention here is rearranging content on the screen to allow space for the keyboard. I believe the accessory view is for attaching additional keyboard specific functionality to the keyboard.

Comment: You can use my gist it's well commented, it's made for views with ScrollView, but you can just change the scrollView part to your UIView it works perfectly.
https://gist.github.com/Sjahriyar/916e93153a29dc602b45f29d39182352

Comment: I've been struggling for days to fix the animation issue with text view. For me UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame fixed the issue. It works perfectly with this notification instead of keyboardDidShowNotification or keyboardWillShowNotification notifications. Please mark UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame in bold to highlight it.

Comment: How would I do this for a UI Created programmatically? Do I just define a let `bottomConstraint` in the viewController and then add it in `NSLayoutConstraint.activate[]`?

Comment: got it to work will make a new answer. But there was a correction in the constraint setting. `self.keyboardHeightLayoutConstraint?.constant = endFrame?.size.height ?? 0.0` this should be `self.discussionsMessageBoxBottomAnchor.constant = -1 * (endFrame?.size.height ?? 0.0)`

Comment: @ParthTamane I think it depends which way round the constraint is made. The original answer was written before iOS had anchors (or is that just the name you gave a constraint).

Comment: The anchor is a NSLayoutConstraint. But the constraint is based on anchor: view.bottomAnchor

Answer (score 133):

If you're using Auto Layout, I assume you've set the **Bottom Space to Superview** constraint. If that's the case, you simply have to update the constraint's value. Here's how you do it with a little bit of animation.

```
func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {
    let info = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height + 20
    })
}
```

The hardcoded 20 is added only to pop the textfield above the keyboard just a bit. Otherwise the keyboard's top margin and textfield's bottom margin would be touching.

When the keyboard is dismissed, reset the constraint's value to its original one.

Comment: Can you explain me pls how i define it? Thanks! i always control all on storyboard

Comment: Select the textfield, go to Editor -> pin and then you'll see some constraint options.

Comment: yep i have it but when i use         self.bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height + 20
 i don't have a member named bottomConstraint. Thanks!!

Comment: bottomConstraint is the name I gave to the constraint. I selected the constrant, dragged and created an IBOutlet to it and gave that name. You can create IBOutlets to constraints just as you could do with other UI elements like buttons and text fields.

Comment: What can I do if I am not using Auto Layout?

Comment: @JoshHarington Have you looked into a library like [this](https://github.com/IdleHandsApps/IHKeyboardAvoiding) one?

Comment: This answer worked great except the animation happened immediately for me. Check [How do I animate constraint changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12664093/1438339) for how to animate properly.

Comment: You need to create an `IBOutlet` for the constraint: `@IBOutlet var constraint_input: NSLayoutConstraint!`

Comment: @Isuru Do I have to set some thing else, because when I gave the above function its not even getting into that function, should I register some notification? Please help

Comment: @vinbhai4u You have to register for `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` notification. Look at the code in the OP's question.

Comment: @Isuru I am trying to achieve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533285/scrollview-with-tab-bar can you please take a look at the question I have asked? it would be a great help

Comment: Thanks @Isuru I got the answer and posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533285/scrollview-with-tab-bar thanks for your help

Comment: @AdamJohns To animate the constraint change, update the constant outside the `animateWithDuration` and call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` inside the animate block.

Comment: Nice answer, Thanks. It's always better to update constraint instead of frame, and it's simple.

Comment: `bottomConstraint` is not valid

Comment: This worked for me, I created a top constraint with priority 999 and a bottom constraint with constant >= 0. So when keyboard pushes layout up the top constraint will allow it as it has lower priority

Comment: What if you have a tableView above the view you are trying to move?  I got the code to work in a separate view, with no constraints (Table views) above it, but how would you handle the above constraint?

Comment: I concur with @Max. To properly animate it you should update the constraint before calling the animateWithDuration method and then inside this method just call layoutIfNeeded over the self.view

Comment: Consider `bottomConstraint.constant` value should be negative.

Answer (score 128):

A simple solution is to move view up with constant of keyboard height.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()        
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
     self.view.frame.origin.y = -150 // Move view 150 points upward 
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
     self.view.frame.origin.y = 0 // Move view to original position  
}
```

**Swift 5:**

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(sender:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(sender:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
```

Comment: I like this simple solution.  But I added a keyboardShowing boolean since I have move than one textfield.  I only move the keyboard once while it is showing.  Thanks.

Comment: instead of moving the view, move the textView

Comment: This will keep minus the view's y value if user switch the input language.

Comment: instead of changing the self.view i did self.myConstraint value, it works but the thing is the view (to which constraint is applied) keeps on moving up. did anyone face this issue ?

Comment: You are adding constraint constant which will affect the view to which that constraint is attached. @Sashi

Comment: Yea, I figured that out after a while. I was adding some specified number of pixels every time keyboard is clicked, but forgot to remove that while hiding keyboard. Now the view moves correctly, but is there a way to make that transition smooth? Like animating it up by that pixels?

Comment: There are no pixels in iOS instead there are points. For animation see this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693130/move-textfield-when-keyboard-appears-swift or better ask new question.

Comment: I like this simple solution, but ti does not work for me. I can see the view being moved, but then it resets back to it's original place/frame.  It is as if ViewDidLayoutSubviews are interfering..

Comment: Or maybe it has something to do with AutoLayout?

Comment: It is not changing any layout constraint. Add a breakpoint in keyboardWillHide function to check when it is being called.

Comment: @Sashi could you post your solution please? currently facing the same issue

Comment: The code is nice..but the problem is when you tap on different textfields in a single viewcontroller repeatedly then it actually moving the complete view continuously and throughing the textfields out of the screen...

Comment: Instead of using `self.view.frame.origin.y -= 150` use `self.view.frame.origin.y = -150` and instead of `self.view.frame.origin.y += 150` use `self.view.frame.origin.y = 0`. This prevents the view moving 150 each time a new field is touched.

Comment: It is working fine. but animation is missing. Thanks

Answer (score 47):

For moving your view while editing textfield try this , I have applied this ,

**Option 1 :- ** **Update in Swift 5.0 and iPhone X , XR , XS and XS Max**
 Move using NotificationCenter

- Register this Notification in `func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)`
- Deregister this Notification in `func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)`

**Note:- If you will not deregister than it will call from child class and will reason of crashing or else.**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver( self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name:  UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil )
}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow( notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        var newHeight: CGFloat
        let duration:TimeInterval = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0
        let animationCurveRawNSN = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
        let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.uintValue ?? UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut.rawValue
        let animationCurve:UIView.AnimationOptions = UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            newHeight = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue.height - self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        } else {
            newHeight = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue.height
        }
        let keyboardHeight = newHeight  + 10 // **10 is bottom margin of View**  and **this newHeight will be keyboard height**
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
                       delay: TimeInterval(0),
                       options: animationCurve,
                       animations: {
                        self.view.textViewBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight **//Here you can manage your view constraints for animated show**
                        self.view.layoutIfNeeded() },
                       completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**Option 2 :-** 
Its work fine

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        self.animateViewMoving(up: true, moveValue: 100)
}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        self.animateViewMoving(up: false, moveValue: 100)
}

func animateViewMoving (up:Bool, moveValue :CGFloat){
    var movementDuration:NSTimeInterval = 0.3
    var movement:CGFloat = ( up ? -moveValue : moveValue)
    UIView.beginAnimations( "animateView", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration )
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0,  movement)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

I got this answer from this source **[UITextField move up when keyboard appears in Swift](http://www.jogendra.com/2015/01/uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard.html)**

IN the Swift 4 ---

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        animateViewMoving(up: true, moveValue: 100)
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        animateViewMoving(up: false, moveValue: 100)
    }
    func animateViewMoving (up:Bool, moveValue :CGFloat){
        let movementDuration:TimeInterval = 0.3
        let movement:CGFloat = ( up ? -moveValue : moveValue)
        UIView.beginAnimations( "animateView", context: nil)
        UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration ) 
        self.view.frame = self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: movement)
        UIView.commitAnimations()
    }
```

Comment: @Jogendra.Com,Thanks for your hard work.But,It work best on iPhone 5,4s and 6.But,how can i disable it on iPhone 6plus and iPad (higher ones)

Comment: If you are using Option 1, please be sure to add a constraint IBOutlet. You will create a constraint that you want to resize using Auto-layout then drag and drop it to the viewcontroller to create an IBOutlet that I reference it as self.iboutletConstraint.constant in the animate function. Also this does not  re-adjust the outlet on hiding the keyboard, I handled that by resetting the constraint to it's original value.

Answer (score 22):

I love clean Swift code. So here's the tightest code I could come up with to move a text view up/down with the keyboard. It's currently working in an iOS8/9 Swift 2 production app.

UPDATE (March 2016):
I just tightened up my previous code as much as possible. Also, there are a bunch of popular answers here that hardcode the keyboard height and animation parameters. There's no need for that, not to mention that the numbers in these answers don't always line up with the actual values I'm seeing on my 6s+ iOS9 (keyboard height of 226, duration of 0.25, and animation curve of 7). In any case, it's almost no extra code to get those values straight from the system. See below.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "animateWithKeyboard:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "animateWithKeyboard:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func animateWithKeyboard(notification: NSNotification) {

    // Based on both Apple's docs and personal experience, 
    // I assume userInfo and its documented keys are available.
    // If you'd like, you can remove the forced unwrapping and add your own default values.

    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardHeight = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue().height
    let duration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
    let curve = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt
    let moveUp = (notification.name == UIKeyboardWillShowNotification)

    // baseContraint is your Auto Layout constraint that pins the
    // text view to the bottom of the superview.

    baseConstraint.constant = moveUp ? -keyboardHeight : 0

    let options = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve << 16)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, options: options,
        animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        },
        completion: nil
    )

}
```

NOTE: This code covers the most comment/general case. However, more code may be needed to handle different orientations and/or custom keyboards [Here's an in-depth article](http://macoscope.com/blog/working-with-keyboard-on-ios/) on working with the iOS keyboard. If you need to handle every scenario, this may help.

Comment: Seems to be Swift 1.1 and I think won't compile in Swift 1.2 because it uses `as` for force casts. `as!` may work but as you can see elsewhere on this page I avoid force casts and force unwrapping myself.

Comment: Compiles now in Swift 1.2. And I added a comment to the code re: the forced unwrapping. Cheers.

Comment: Oops. I meant Swift 2.

Comment: Depending on how you linked up your `baseConstraint` it might be `baseConstraint.constant = moveUp ? keyboardHeight : 0` instead of `baseConstraint.constant = moveUp ? -keyboardHeight : 0`.

Answer (score 15):

**Edit**: I recommend an easier and cleaner solution. Just change the class of bottom spacing constraint to [KeyboardLayoutConstraint](https://github.com/MengTo/Spring/blob/master/Spring/KeyboardLayoutConstraint.swift). It will automatically expand to the keyboard height.

---

This is an improved version of @JosephLord 's answer.

As tested on iOS 8.3 iPad Simulator, Portrait. Xcode6.3 beta4, I found his answer doesn't work when keyboard is hiding because `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` is `"NSRect: {{0, 1024}, {768, 264}}";`. The height is never `0`.

This goes back to use the traditional `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` to better tell when keyboard is hiding rather than relying on the end frame's height. `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` is also sent when keyboard frame is changed so it should cover all use cases.

```
    // You have to set this up in storyboard first!. 
    // It's a vertical spacing constraint between view and bottom of superview.
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomSpacingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardNotification:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardNotification:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
    }

    deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }

    func keyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {

        let isShowing = notification.name == UIKeyboardWillShowNotification

        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            let endFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue()
            let endFrameHeight = endFrame?.size.height ?? 0.0
            let duration:NSTimeInterval = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0
            let animationCurveRawNSN = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
            let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.unsignedLongValue ?? UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut.rawValue
            let animationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)
            self.bottomSpacingConstraint?.constant = isShowing ? endFrameHeight : 0.0
            UIView.animateWithDuration(duration,
                delay: NSTimeInterval(0),
                options: animationCurve,
                animations: { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() },
                completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please explain your edit? I couldn't get it to work. I have a UIScrollView with a Button at the bottom. I setted the class at the margin bottom constraint on the bottom.

Comment: @schw4ndi to what views does your bottom constraints tied to? it should be connecting bottom of scrollview to the bottom of that scrollview's superview.

Comment: Oh thanks, i had the constraint between the button and the scrollView

Answer (score 10):

i am working with **swift 4** and i am solved this issue without use any extra bottom constraint look my code is here.its really working on my case

**1) Add Notification Observer in did load**

> ```
> override func viewDidLoad() {
>         super.viewDidLoad()
>         setupManager()
>         // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
>         NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
>         NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
>     }
> ```

**2) Remove Notification Observer like**

> ```
> deinit {
>         NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
>     }
> ```

**3) Add keyboard show/ hide methods like**

```
 @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
            if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                })
            }
        }

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }
    }
```

**4) Add textfeild delegate and add touchesBegan methods .usefull for hide the keyboard when touch outside the textfeild on screen**

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        view.endEditing(true)

    }
```

Comment: needs to be `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`

Comment: `NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow `
 is Renamed to `UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification`
also 
`UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey ` to `UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`

Answer (score 9):

You can use this library and just one line of code in appDidFinishedLaunching and u are done..

```
func application(application: UIApplication,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
    return true
}
```

IQKeyboardManager - adjust view whenever keyboard appear
link - https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: Yeah it's nice. But do you really need to use this library for this simple problem? It's just convenience.

Comment: @Rhenz just for convenience dude, we can always choose not to, but this IQKeyboardManager do a lot of things apart from just moving the UI above the keyboard

Answer (score 8):

This is an improved version of @JosephLord and @Hlung's answer. 
It can apply whether you have tabbar or not. 
And it would perfectly restore view that is moved by keyboard to original position.

```
// You have to set this up in storyboard first!. 
// It's a vertical spacing constraint between view and bottom of superview.
@IBOutlet weak var bottomSpacingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! 

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()            

        //    Receive(Get) Notification
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardNotification:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardNotification:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)


        self.originalConstraint = self.keyboardHeightLayoutConstraint?.constant //for original coordinate.
}

func keyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
        let isShowing = notification.name == UIKeyboardWillShowNotification

        var tabbarHeight: CGFloat = 0
        if self.tabBarController? != nil {
            tabbarHeight = self.tabBarController!.tabBar.frame.height
        }
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            let endFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue()
            let duration:NSTimeInterval = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0
            let animationCurveRawNSN = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
            let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.unsignedLongValue ?? UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut.rawValue
            let animationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)
            self.keyboardHeightLayoutConstraint?.constant = isShowing ? (endFrame!.size.height - tabbarHeight) : self.originalConstraint!
            UIView.animateWithDuration(duration,
                delay: NSTimeInterval(0),
                options: animationCurve,
                animations: { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() },
                completion: nil)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I created a Swift 3 protocol to handle the keyboard appearance / disappearance

```
import UIKit

protocol KeyboardHandler: class {

var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! { get set }

    func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification)
    func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification)
    func startObservingKeyboardChanges()
    func stopObservingKeyboardChanges()
}


extension KeyboardHandler where Self: UIViewController {

    func startObservingKeyboardChanges() {

        // NotificationCenter observers
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
          self?.keyboardWillShow(notification)
        }

        // Deal with rotations
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
          self?.keyboardWillShow(notification)
        }

        // Deal with keyboard change (emoji, numerical, etc.)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChange, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
          self?.keyboardWillShow(notification)
        }

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
          self?.keyboardWillHide(notification)
        }
    }


    func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {

      let verticalPadding: CGFloat = 20 // Padding between the bottom of the view and the top of the keyboard

      guard let value = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }
      let keyboardHeight = value.cgRectValue.height

      // Here you could have more complex rules, like checking if the textField currently selected is actually covered by the keyboard, but that's out of this scope.
      self.bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight + verticalPadding

      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
          self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
      })
  }


  func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
      self.bottomConstraint.constant = 0

      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
          self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
      })
  }


  func stopObservingKeyboardChanges() {
      NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
  }

}
```

Then, to implement it in a UIViewController, do the following:

- let the viewController conform to this protocol :

  ```
  class FormMailVC: UIViewControlle, KeyboardHandler {
  ```
- start observing keyboard changes in viewWillAppear:

  ```
  // MARK: - View controller life cycle
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    startObservingKeyboardChanges()
  }
  ```
- stop observing keyboard changes in viewWillDisappear:

  ```
  override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    stopObservingKeyboardChanges()
  }
  ```
- create an IBOutlet for the bottom constraint from the storyboard:

  ```
  // NSLayoutConstraints
  @IBOutlet weak var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
  ```

  (I recommend having all of your UI embedded inside a "contentView", and linking to this property the bottom constraint from this contentView to the bottom layout guide)
  [image: Content view bottom constraint]
- change the constraint priority of the *top constraint* to 250 (low)

[image: Content view top constraint]

This is to let the whole content view slide upwards when the keyboard appears.
The priority must be lower than any other constraint priority in the subviews, including content hugging priorities / content compression resistance priorities.

- Make sure that your Autolayout has enough constraints to determine how the contentView should slide up.

You may have to add a "greater than equal" constraint for this:
[image: "greater than equal" constraint]

And here you go!
[image: Without keyboard]

[image: With keyboard]

Comment: It's worked if you put "Relation = Equal" too, without warnings.

Comment: If you put an equal relationship, it may work only in specific situations. In others you may have an auto layout inconsistency warning. It depends on your own layout. That's why I said "you may have to".

Comment: Ok Frédéric, agreeded. Was a nice solution!

Comment: missing `import UIKit`

Answer (score 8):

Complete code for managing keyboard.

```
        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(StoryMediaVC.keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(StoryMediaVC.keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        }
        override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        }
        @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
            guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else {return}
            guard let keyboardSize = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else {return}
            let keyboardFrame = keyboardSize.cgRectValue

            if self.view.bounds.origin.y == 0{
                self.view.bounds.origin.y += keyboardFrame.height
            }
        }


        @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
            if self.view.bounds.origin.y != 0 {
                self.view.bounds.origin.y = 0
            }
        }
```

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: if you got nothing, then use this solution. perfect one to rescue you.

Comment: working perfectly

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way that doesn't require any code:

1. Download [KeyboardLayoutConstraint.swift](https://github.com/MengTo/Spring/blob/master/Spring/KeyboardLayoutConstraint.swift) and add (drag & drop) the file into your project, if you're not using the Spring animation framework already.
2. In your storyboard, create a bottom constraint for the object/view/textfield, select the constraint (double-click it) and in the Identity Inspector, change its class from NSLayoutConstraint to KeyboardLayoutConstraint.
3. Done!

The object will auto-move up with the keyboard, in sync.

Comment: Great solution! But you need the Safe Area.Bottom as the first item on the constraint (didn't work for me when it was the second item). And it worked best with the constant set to 0 as it preserves the constant and adjusts it, rather than just moving it far enough to show the field and  keyboard.

Comment: Do you have  KeyboardLayoutConstraint swift4 version ?

Answer (score 6):

Such simple `UIViewController` **extension** can be used

```
//MARK: - Observers
extension UIViewController {

    func addObserverForNotification(notificationName: String, actionBlock: (NSNotification) -> Void) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(notificationName, object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), usingBlock: actionBlock)
    }

    func removeObserver(observer: AnyObject, notificationName: String) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(observer, name: notificationName, object: nil)
    }
}

//MARK: - Keyboard observers
extension UIViewController {

    typealias KeyboardHeightClosure = (CGFloat) -> ()

    func addKeyboardChangeFrameObserver(willShow willShowClosure: KeyboardHeightClosure?,
        willHide willHideClosure: KeyboardHeightClosure?) {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification,
                object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), usingBlock: { [weak self](notification) in
                    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
                        let frame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue(),
                        let duration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double,
                        let c = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? UInt,
                        let kFrame = self?.view.convertRect(frame, fromView: nil),
                        let kBounds = self?.view.bounds {

                            let animationType = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: c)
                            let kHeight = kFrame.size.height
                            UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, options: animationType, animations: {
                                if CGRectIntersectsRect(kBounds, kFrame) { // keyboard will be shown
                                    willShowClosure?(kHeight)
                                } else { // keyboard will be hidden
                                    willHideClosure?(kHeight)
                                }
                                }, completion: nil)
                    } else {
                            print("Invalid conditions for UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification")
                    }
            })
    }

    func removeKeyboardObserver() {
        removeObserver(self, notificationName: UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification)
    }
}
```

Example of usage

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        removeKeyboardObserver()
    }

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    addKeyboardChangeFrameObserver(willShow: { [weak self](height) in
        //Update constraints here
        self?.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        }, willHide: { [weak self](height) in
        //Reset constraints here
        self?.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    })
}
```

**Swift 4 solution**

```
//MARK: - Observers
extension UIViewController {

  func addObserverForNotification(_ notificationName: Notification.Name, actionBlock: @escaping (Notification) -> Void) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: notificationName, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main, using: actionBlock)
  }

  func removeObserver(_ observer: AnyObject, notificationName: Notification.Name) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer, name: notificationName, object: nil)
  }
}

//MARK: - Keyboard handling
extension UIViewController {

  typealias KeyboardHeightClosure = (CGFloat) -> ()

  func addKeyboardChangeFrameObserver(willShow willShowClosure: KeyboardHeightClosure?,
                                      willHide willHideClosure: KeyboardHeightClosure?) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame,
                                           object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main, using: { [weak self](notification) in
                                            if let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
                                              let frame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue,
                                              let duration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double,
                                              let c = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? UInt,
                                              let kFrame = self?.view.convert(frame, from: nil),
                                              let kBounds = self?.view.bounds {

                                              let animationType = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: c)
                                              let kHeight = kFrame.size.height
                                              UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: animationType, animations: {
                                                if kBounds.intersects(kFrame) { // keyboard will be shown
                                                  willShowClosure?(kHeight)
                                                } else { // keyboard will be hidden
                                                  willHideClosure?(kHeight)
                                                }
                                              }, completion: nil)
                                            } else {
                                              print("Invalid conditions for UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification")
                                            }
    })
  }

  func removeKeyboardObserver() {
    removeObserver(self, notificationName: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame)
  }
}
```

**Swift 4.2**

```
//MARK: - Keyboard handling
extension UIViewController {

    func addObserverForNotification(_ notificationName: Notification.Name, actionBlock: @escaping (Notification) -> Void) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: notificationName, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main, using: actionBlock)
    }

    func removeObserver(_ observer: AnyObject, notificationName: Notification.Name) {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer, name: notificationName, object: nil)
    }

    typealias KeyboardHeightClosure = (CGFloat) -> ()

    func removeKeyboardObserver() {
        removeObserver(self, notificationName: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification)
    }

    func addKeyboardChangeFrameObserver(willShow willShowClosure: KeyboardHeightClosure?,
                                        willHide willHideClosure: KeyboardHeightClosure?) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification,
                                               object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main, using: { [weak self](notification) in
                                                if let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
                                                    let frame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue,
                                                    let duration = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double,
                                                    let c = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? UInt,
                                                    let kFrame = self?.view.convert(frame, from: nil),
                                                    let kBounds = self?.view.bounds {

                                                    let animationType = UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: c)
                                                    let kHeight = kFrame.size.height
                                                    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: animationType, animations: {
                                                        if kBounds.intersects(kFrame) { // keyboard will be shown
                                                            willShowClosure?(kHeight)
                                                        } else { // keyboard will be hidden
                                                            willHideClosure?(kHeight)
                                                        }
                                                    }, completion: nil)
                                                } else {
                                                    print("Invalid conditions for UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification")
                                                }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: much more "Swift" than the other solutions  / works great  / reusable in every controller without rewriting everything  -> definitely the best one here :)

Comment: I tried but no chance, is UIScrollView needed or what?

Comment: @erdemgc did you see Example of usage? All you need is just UIViewControlller + addKeyboardChangeFrameObserver and then do not forget to remove it

Comment: The `removeKeyboardObserver()` method here does not actually remove the observer. If you don't call this, you will see a `Invalid conditions for UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` in the console from the add method. If you call this, you will see the same error, meaning the observer isn't removed. The documentation states "To unregister observations, you pass the object returned by this method to `removeObserver(_:)`." So what you do instead is save the object returned by that method, then pass it in when you want to remove the observer.

Comment: Actually, once scrollview is loaded, bound is assigned a value and you can't detect if a keyboard will be hidden if keyboard frame intersects with bound.

Comment: @Hemang you can update any constraint you need. this closures shows you height of keyboard

Answer (score 5):

A `Swift 5` solution for [frédéric-adda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1552730/fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric-adda) :

```
protocol KeyboardHandler: class {
    var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! { get set }
    
    func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification)
    func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification)
    func startObservingKeyboardChanges()
    func stopObservingKeyboardChanges()
}


extension KeyboardHandler where Self: UIViewController {

    func startObservingKeyboardChanges() {

        // NotificationCenter observers
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
          self?.keyboardWillShow(notification)
        }

        // Deal with rotations
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
          self?.keyboardWillShow(notification)
        }

        // Deal with keyboard change (emoji, numerical, etc.)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UITextInputMode.currentInputModeDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
          self?.keyboardWillShow(notification)
        }

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
          self?.keyboardWillHide(notification)
        }
    }


    func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {

      let verticalPadding: CGFloat = 20 // Padding between the bottom of the view and the top of the keyboard

        guard let value = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }
      let keyboardHeight = value.cgRectValue.height

      // Here you could have more complex rules, like checking if the textField currently selected is actually covered by the keyboard, but that's out of this scope.
      self.bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight + verticalPadding

      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
          self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
      })
  }


  func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
      self.bottomConstraint.constant = 0

      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
          self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
      })
  }


  func stopObservingKeyboardChanges() {
      NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
  }
}
```

In any `UIViewController`:

- Conform to `KeyboardHandler` protocol

```
extension AnyViewController: KeyboardHandler {}
```

- Add bottom constraint for the last-bottom element on the screen.

```
@IBOutlet var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

- Add Observer subscribe/unsubscribe:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        startObservingKeyboardChanges()
 }
    
 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        stopObservingKeyboardChanges()
 }
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

```
struct MoveKeyboard {
    static let KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION : CGFloat = 0.3
    static let MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION : CGFloat = 0.2;
    static let MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION : CGFloat = 0.8;
    static let PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT : CGFloat = 216;
    static let LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT : CGFloat = 162;
}


  func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    let textFieldRect : CGRect = self.view.window!.convertRect(textField.bounds, fromView: textField)
    let viewRect : CGRect = self.view.window!.convertRect(self.view.bounds, fromView: self.view)

    let midline : CGFloat = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height
    let numerator : CGFloat = midline - viewRect.origin.y - MoveKeyboard.MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height
    let denominator : CGFloat = (MoveKeyboard.MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MoveKeyboard.MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION) * viewRect.size.height
    var heightFraction : CGFloat = numerator / denominator

    if heightFraction < 0.0 {
        heightFraction = 0.0
    } else if heightFraction > 1.0 {
        heightFraction = 1.0
    }

    let orientation : UIInterfaceOrientation = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown) {
        animateDistance = floor(MoveKeyboard.PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction)
    } else {
        animateDistance = floor(MoveKeyboard.LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction)
    }

    var viewFrame : CGRect = self.view.frame
    viewFrame.origin.y -= animateDistance

    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(NSTimeInterval(MoveKeyboard.KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION))

    self.view.frame = viewFrame

    UIView.commitAnimations()
}


func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    var viewFrame : CGRect = self.view.frame
    viewFrame.origin.y += animateDistance

    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)

    UIView.setAnimationDuration(NSTimeInterval(MoveKeyboard.KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION))

    self.view.frame = viewFrame

    UIView.commitAnimations()

}
```

And Lastly since we are using delegates methods

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
```

refactored from using objective-c http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/sliding-uitextfields-around-to-avoid.html

Comment: This solution worked for me, although I had to do some additional work: declare an `var animateDistance: CGFloat!` plus I had to handle the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification for when the user presses the hide keyboard button.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution that doesn't depend on autolayout, constraints or any outlets. What you do need is your field(s) in a scrollview.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "makeSpaceForKeyboard:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "makeSpaceForKeyboard:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func makeSpaceForKeyboard(notification: NSNotification) {
    let info = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardHeight:CGFloat = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue().size.height
    let duration:Double = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double

    if notification.name == UIKeyboardWillShowNotification {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: { () -> Void in
            var frame = self.view.frame
            frame.size.height = frame.size.height - keyboardHeight
            self.view.frame = frame
        })
    } else {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: { () -> Void in
            var frame = self.view.frame
            frame.size.height = frame.size.height + keyboardHeight
            self.view.frame = frame
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: It showing black screen after `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` called.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my version for a solution for Swift 2.2:

First register for Keyboard Show/Hide Notifications

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
                                                 selector: #selector(MessageThreadVC.keyboardWillShow(_:)),
                                                 name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification,
                                                 object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
                                                 selector: #selector(MessageThreadVC.keyboardWillHide(_:)),
                                                 name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification,
                                                 object: nil)
```

Then in methods coresponding for those notifications move the main view up or down

```
func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
if let keyboardSize = (sender.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
  self.view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardSize.height
  }
}

func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
}
```

The trick is in the "keyboardWillShow" part which get calls every time "QuickType Suggestion Bar" is expanded or collapsed. Then we always set the y coordinate of the main view which equals the negative value of total keyboard height (with or without the "QuickType bar" portion).

At the end do not forget to remove observers

```
deinit {
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following is a simple solution, whereby the text field has a constraint tying it to the bottom layout guide. It simply adds the keyboard height to the constraint's constant.

```
// This constraint ties the text field to the bottom layout guide
@IBOutlet var textFieldToBottomLayoutGuideConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
}

func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (sender.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        self.textFieldToBottomLayoutGuideConstraint?.constant += keyboardSize.height
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (sender.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        self.textFieldToBottomLayoutGuideConstraint?.constant -= keyboardSize.height
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, I think i might be too late but i found another simple version of Saqib's answer. I'm using Autolayout with constraints. I have a small view inside of another main view with username and password fields. Instead of changing the y coordinate of the view i'm saving the original constraint value in a variable and changing the constraint's constant to some value and again after the keyboard dismisses, i'm setting up the constraint to original one. This way it avoids the problem Saqib's answer has, (The view keeps on moving up and does not stop). Below is my code...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
    self.originalConstraint = self.centerYConstraint.constant
  }

  func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    self.centerYConstraint.constant += 30
  }

  func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    self.centerYConstraint.constant = self.originalConstraint
  }
```

Comment: Inside  **keyboardWillShow** method check for the condition **if self.centerYConstraint.constant == self.originalCenterYConstraint** then have that one line of code in between this condition. OriginalCenterYContraint is the original value of centerYContraint that I'm storing in viewdidload. This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4.x answer, merging answers from @Joseph Lord and @Isuru. `bottomConstraint` represents the bottom constraint of the view you're interested in moving.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // Call super
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Subscribe to keyboard notifications
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(keyboardNotification(notification:)),
                                           name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification,
                                           object: nil)        
}


deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}


@objc func keyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        // Get keyboard frame
        let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue

        // Set new bottom constraint constant
        let bottomConstraintConstant = keyboardFrame.origin.y >= UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height ? 0.0 : keyboardFrame.size.height

        // Set animation properties
        let duration = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0
        let animationCurveRawNSN = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
        let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.uintValue ?? UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut.rawValue
        let animationCurve = UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)

        // Animate the view you care about
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: animationCurve, animations: {
            self.bottomConstraint.constant = bottomConstraintConstant
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Very Simple and no need to code more.
Just add `pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'` in your podfile, and in your `AppDelegate` page add code below.

```
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift
```

and in method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions()` type

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
```

that is it.
check this video link for better understanding https://youtu.be/eOM94K1ZWN8
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Does it work for TextView and how can I change title for return key "Done" ?

Comment: Goto:- "IQKeyboardManager.m"
Replace this line(Line No. 968):-
[textField addDoneOnKeyboardWithTarget:self action:@selector(doneAction:) shouldShowPlaceholder:_shouldShowTextFieldPlaceholder]                                                      with this:-
[textField addRightButtonOnKeyboardWithText:@"YOURTEXT" target:self action:@selector(doneAction:) shouldShowPlaceholder:_shouldShowTextFieldPlaceholder];                   And haven't tried yet for the textview, hope this would help you.

Answer (score 2):

### I have done by following manner:

This is useful when textfield superview is view

```
class AdminLoginViewController: UIViewController,
UITextFieldDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var txtUserName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtUserPassword: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnAdminLogin: UIButton!

    private var activeField : UIView?

    var param:String!
    var adminUser : Admin? = nil
    var kbHeight: CGFloat!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        self.addKeyBoardObserver()
        self.addGestureForHideKeyBoard()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func addGestureForHideKeyBoard()
    {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("hideKeyboard"))
        tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    func hideKeyboard() {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func addKeyBoardObserver(){

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "willChangeKeyboardFrame:",
name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "willChangeKeyboardFrame:",
name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func removeObserver(){
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }

    //MARK:- textfiled Delegate

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
         activeField = textField

        return true
    }
    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
        if activeField == textField
        {
            activeField = nil
        }

        return true
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        if txtUserName == textField
        {
            txtUserPassword.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        else if (textField == txtUserPassword)
        {
            self.btnAdminLoginAction(nil)
        }
        return true;
    }

    func willChangeKeyboardFrame(aNotification : NSNotification)
    {
       if self.activeField != nil && self.activeField!.isFirstResponder()
    {
        if let keyboardSize =  (aNotification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue()
        {
            let dy = (self.activeField?.superview?.convertRect((self.activeField?.frame)!, toView: view).origin.y)!

            let height = (self.view.frame.size.height - keyboardSize.size.height)

            if dy > height
            {
                var frame = self.view.frame

                frame.origin.y = -((dy - height) + (self.activeField?.frame.size.height)! + 20)

                self.view.frame = frame
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var frame = self.view.frame
        frame.origin.y = 0
        self.view.frame = frame
    }
    } }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    func registerForKeyboardNotifications(){
        //Keyboard
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown), name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden), name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)


    }
    func deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications(){

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

    }
    func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification){

        let userInfo: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardInfoFrame = userInfo.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey)?.CGRectValue()

        let windowFrame:CGRect = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.convertRect(self.view.frame, fromView:self.view))

        let keyboardFrame = CGRectIntersection(windowFrame, keyboardInfoFrame!)

        let coveredFrame = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.convertRect(keyboardFrame, toView:self.view)

        let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, (coveredFrame.size.height), 0.0)
        self.scrollViewInAddCase .contentInset = contentInsets;
        self.scrollViewInAddCase.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
        self.scrollViewInAddCase.contentSize = CGSizeMake((self.scrollViewInAddCase.contentSize.width), (self.scrollViewInAddCase.contentSize.height))

    }
    /**
     this method will fire when keyboard was hidden

     - parameter notification: contains keyboard details
     */
    func keyboardWillBeHidden (notification: NSNotification) {

        self.scrollViewInAddCase.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        self.scrollViewInAddCase.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero

    }
```

Comment: Use above code to move the textfield above the keyboard in swift 2.2 it will work’s fine . i hope it will help some one.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone not using storyboards to set the layout constraint. This is a pure programmatic way to get it working on Swift 5:

1. Define an empty constraint in your viewController. In this case, I am building a chat app that has a UIView containing text view at the very bottom of the screen.

```
var discussionsMessageBoxBottomAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
```

2. In viewDidLoad add the constraints for the bottom-most view. In this case `discussionsMessageBox`. Also, add the listener for keyboard events.

*For correctly initializing the constraint, you need to first add the subview and then define the constraint.*

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(self.keyboardNotification(notification:)),
                                       name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame,
                                       object: nil)

view.addSubview(discussionsMessageBox)

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    discussionsMessageBoxBottomAnchor = discussionsMessageBox.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
    discussionsMessageBoxBottomAnchor = discussionsMessageBox.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
}

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([ discussionsMessageBoxBottomAnchor ])
```

3. Define `deinit`.

```
deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
```

4. Next add the code that @JosephLord defined, with one correction to fix offset math.

```
extension DiscussionsViewController {
    @objc func keyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }
        
        let endFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
        let endFrameY = endFrame?.origin.y ?? 0
        let duration:TimeInterval = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0
        let animationCurveRawNSN = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
        let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.uintValue ?? UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut.rawValue
        let animationCurve:UIView.AnimationOptions = UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)
        
        if endFrameY >= UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height {
            self.discussionsMessageBoxBottomAnchor.constant = 0.0
        } else {
            //Changed line
            self.discussionsMessageBoxBottomAnchor.constant = -1 * (endFrame?.size.height ?? 0.0)
        }
        
        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: duration,
            delay: TimeInterval(0),
            options: animationCurve,
            animations: { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() },
            completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one text field on the view, then I suggest that you look at this method. When switching between fields, you will not have a problem with the fact that the view runs away, it will simply adapt to the desired text field. It works in swift 5

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    registerForKeyboardNotification()
}
```

All methods in extensions

```
extension StartViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

func registerForKeyboardNotification() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(sender:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(sender:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil) 
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    guard let userInfo = sender.userInfo,
          let keyboardFrame = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue,
          let currentTextField = UIResponder.currentFirst() as? UITextField  else { return }
         
    let keyboardTopY = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue.origin.y
    let convertedTextFieldFrame = view.convert(currentTextField.frame, from: currentTextField.superview)
    let textFieldBottomY = convertedTextFieldFrame.origin.y + convertedTextFieldFrame.size.height
    
    if textFieldBottomY > keyboardTopY {
        let textBoxY = convertedTextFieldFrame.origin.y
        let newFrameY = (textBoxY - keyboardTopY / 2) * -1
        view.frame.origin.y = newFrameY
    }
}


@objc func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
     self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
}


func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    switch textField {
    case emailTextField :
        passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    default:
        emailTextField.becomeFirstResponder()  
    }
    return true
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches , with:event)
    view.endEditing(true)
}
}
```

At the end we set up the method with UIResponder

```
extension UIResponder {
private struct Static {
    static weak var responder: UIResponder?
}

static func currentFirst() -> UIResponder? {
    Static.responder = nil
    UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder._trap), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    return Static.responder
}

@objc private func _trap() {
    Static.responder = self
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done in following manner :

```
class SignInController: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

// outlet declartion
@IBOutlet weak var signInTextView: UITextField!

var kbHeight: CGFloat!

/**
*
* @method viewDidLoad
*
*/

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.signInTextView.delegate = self

}// end viewDidLoad

/**
*
* @method viewWillAppear
*
*/

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

}// end viewWillAppear

/**
*
* @method viewDidAppear
*
*/

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)


}// end viewDidAppear

/**
*
* @method viewWillDisappear
*
*/
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

/**
*
* @method textFieldShouldReturn
* retun the keyboard value
*
*/

// MARK -
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    signInTextView.resignFirstResponder()
    return true;

}// end textFieldShouldReturn

// MARK - keyboardWillShow
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        if let keyboardSize =  (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            kbHeight = keyboardSize.height
            self.animateTextField(true)
        }
    }
}// end keyboardWillShow

// MARK - keyboardWillHide
func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.animateTextField(false)
}// end keyboardWillHide

// MARK - animateTextField
func animateTextField(up: Bool) {
    var movement = (up ? -kbHeight : kbHeight)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
        self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement)
    })
}// end animateTextField

/**
*
* @method didReceiveMemoryWarning
*
*/

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}// end didReceiveMemoryWarning


}// end SignInController
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are like me who has tried all the above solutions and still your problem is not solved, I have a got a great solution for you that works like a charm. First I want clarify few things about some of solutions mentioned above.

1. In my case IQkeyboardmanager was working only when there is no auto layout applied on the elements, if it is applied then IQkeyboard manager will not work the way we think.
2. Same thing with upward movement of **self.view.**
3. i have wriiten a objective c header with a swift support for pushing UITexfield upward when user clicks on it, solving the problem of keyboard covering the UITextfield : https://github.com/coolvasanth/smart_keyboard.
4. One who has An intermediate or higher level in iOS app development can easily understand the repository and implement it. All the best

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic solution for all TextField
Steps -

1) Create a common ViewController that is extended by other ViewControllers

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

}
 @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= getMoveableDistance(keyboarHeight: keyboardSize.height)
        }
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
        self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
}
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

//get the distance to move up the main view for the focus textfiled
func getMoveableDistance(keyboarHeight : CGFloat) ->  CGFloat{
    var y:CGFloat = 0.0
    if let activeTF = getSelectedTextField(){
        var tfMaxY = activeTF.frame.maxY
        var containerView = activeTF.superview!
        while containerView.frame.maxY != self.view.frame.maxY{
            let contViewFrm = containerView.convert(activeTF.frame, to: containerView.superview)
            tfMaxY = tfMaxY + contViewFrm.minY
            containerView = containerView.superview!
        }
        let keyboardMinY = self.view.frame.height - keyboarHeight
        if tfMaxY > keyboardMinY{
            y = (tfMaxY - keyboardMinY) + 10.0
        }
    }

    return y
}
```

2) Create a extension of UIViewController and the currently active TextField

```
//get active text field
```

extension UIViewController {
    func getSelectedTextField() -> UITextField? {

```
    let totalTextFields = getTextFieldsInView(view: self.view)

    for textField in totalTextFields{
        if textField.isFirstResponder{
            return textField
        }
    }

    return nil

}

func getTextFieldsInView(view: UIView) -> [UITextField] {

    var totalTextFields = [UITextField]()

    for subview in view.subviews as [UIView] {
        if let textField = subview as? UITextField {
            totalTextFields += [textField]
        } else {
            totalTextFields += getTextFieldsInView(view: subview)
        }
    }

    return totalTextFields
}
```

}

Comment: For some reason, I was having an issue in keyboardWillShow function, the keyboardSize was getting wrong size after the first keyboard toggle (the first toggle has correct frame).  I fixed this by changing it to 
guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else {return}
guard let keyboardSize = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else {return}
let keyboardFrame = keyboardSize.cgRectValue
if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
 self.view.frame.origin.y -= getMoveableDistance(keyboarHeight: keyboardFrame.height)
}
.Hope this will help if someone got the same issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I modified @Simpa solution a little bit.........

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{

    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("makeSpaceForKeyboard:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("makeSpaceForKeyboard:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
}

deinit{
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

var keyboardIsVisible = false
override func makeSpaceForKeyboard(notification: NSNotification) {

    let info = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardHeight:CGFloat = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue().size.height
    let duration:Double = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double

    if notification.name == UIKeyboardWillShowNotification && keyboardIsVisible == false{

        keyboardIsVisible = true

        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: { () -> Void in
            var frame = self.view.frame
            frame.size.height = frame.size.height - keyboardHeight
            self.view.frame = frame
        })

    } else if keyboardIsVisible == true && notification.name == UIKeyboardWillShowNotification{

    }else {
        keyboardIsVisible = false

        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: { () -> Void in
            var frame = self.view.frame
            frame.size.height = frame.size.height + keyboardHeight
            self.view.frame = frame
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of them worked for and I ended up using content insets to move my view up when the keyboard appears.

**Note:** I was using a UITableView

Referenced solution @ [keyboard-content-offset](http://kingscocoa.com/tutorials/keyboard-content-offset/) which was entirely written in objective C, the below solution is clean Swift.

Add the notification observer @ viewDidLoad()

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(yourClass.keyboardWillBeShown), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(yourClass.keyboardWillBeHidden), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
```

To get the keyboard size, we first get the userInfo dictionary from the notification object, which stores any additional objects that our receiver might use.

From that dictionary we can get the CGRect object describing the keyboard’s frame by using the key UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey.

Apply the content inset for the table view @ keyboardWillBeShown method,

```
func keyboardWillBeShown(sender: NSNotification)
{        
    // Move the table view

    if let keyboardSize = (sender.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue()
    {
        let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, (keyboardSize.height), 0.0);

        yourTableView.contentInset = contentInsets;

        yourTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    }
}
```

Restore the view @ keyboardWillBeHidden method

```
func keyboardWillBeHidden(sender: NSNotification)
{
    // Moving back the table view back to the default position

    yourTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    yourTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

If you want to keep the device orientation also into consideration, use conditional statements to tailor the code to your needs.

```
// Portrait
UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, (keyboardSize.height), 0.0);

// Landscape
UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, (keyboardSize.width), 0.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWillShow(_ notification:Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.height, 0)
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(_ notification:Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Swift 4 solution I use, takes in keyboard size. Replace `serverStatusStackView` with whatever view you care about, e.g.: `self.view`:

```
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        serverStatusStackView.frame.origin.y = keyboardSize.height * 2 - serverStatusStackView.frame.height
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        serverStatusStackView.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using NotificationCenter to catch keyboard actions. You can follow the steps in this short article
https://medium.com/@demirciy/keyboard-handling-deb1a96a8207

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.1,

Use TPKeyBoardAvoiding class for achieving this.
This works fine with **UIScrollView**, **UICollectionView**, **UITableView**.

Just assign this class to your scrollview, collectionview or tableview in storyboard or create its object programmatically.
All textfield or textviews inside **TPKeyboardAvoiding** scrollview will adjust automatically when the keyboard appears and disappears.

Here is the link for [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/apple-avadhesh/TPKeyboardAvoiding)

**TPKeyboardAvoiding for Swift 4.1,**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

// MARK: - TableView
class TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView:UITableView,UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

    override var frame:CGRect{
        willSet{
            super.frame = frame
        }

        didSet{
            if hasAutomaticKeyboardAvoidingBehaviour() {return}
            TPKeyboardAvoiding_updateContentInset()
        }
    }

    override var contentSize:CGSize{
        willSet(newValue){
            if hasAutomaticKeyboardAvoidingBehaviour() {
                super.contentSize = newValue
                return
            }

            if newValue.equalTo(self.contentSize)
            {
                return
            }

            super.contentSize = newValue
            self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_updateContentInset()
        }

        //        didSet{
        //            self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_updateContentInset()
        //        }
    }


    override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableViewStyle) {
        super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
        self.setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setup()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        setup()
    }

    deinit{
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    func hasAutomaticKeyboardAvoidingBehaviour()->Bool
    {
        if #available(iOS 8.3, *) {
            if self.delegate is UITableViewController
            {
                return true
            }
        }

        return false
    }

    func focusNextTextField()->Bool
    {
        return self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_focusNextTextField()
    }

    @objc func scrollToActiveTextField()
    {
        return self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_scrollToActiveTextField()
    }

    override func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {
        super.willMove(toSuperview: newSuperview)
        if newSuperview != nil {
            NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(TPKeyboardAvoiding_assignTextDelegateForViewsBeneathView(_:)), object: self)
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_findFirstResponderBeneathView(self)?.resignFirstResponder()
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if !self.focusNextTextField()
        {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        return true
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(TPKeyboardAvoiding_assignTextDelegateForViewsBeneathView(_:)), object: self)

        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(TPKeyboardAvoiding_assignTextDelegateForViewsBeneathView(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
}

private extension TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView
{
    func setup()
    {
        if self.hasAutomaticKeyboardAvoidingBehaviour() { return }

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(TPKeyboardAvoiding_keyboardWillShow(_:)),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame,
                                               object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(TPKeyboardAvoiding_keyboardWillHide(_:)),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide,
                                               object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(scrollToActiveTextField),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.UITextViewTextDidBeginEditing,
                                               object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(scrollToActiveTextField),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditing,
                                               object: nil)
    }
}

// MARK: - CollectionView
class TPKeyboardAvoidingCollectionView:UICollectionView,UITextViewDelegate {

    override var contentSize:CGSize{
        willSet(newValue){
            if newValue.equalTo(self.contentSize)
            {
                return
            }

            super.contentSize = newValue
            self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_updateContentInset()
        }

        //        didSet{
        //            self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_updateContentInset()
        //        }
    }


    override var frame:CGRect{
        willSet{
            super.frame = frame
        }

        didSet{
            self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_updateContentInset()
        }
    }

    //    override init(frame: CGRect) {
    //        super.init(frame: frame)
    //    }

    override init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
        super.init(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        //        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setup()

    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        setup()
    }

    deinit{
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    func focusNextTextField()->Bool
    {
        return self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_focusNextTextField()
    }

    @objc func scrollToActiveTextField()
    {
        return self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_scrollToActiveTextField()
    }

    override func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {
        super.willMove(toSuperview: newSuperview)
        if newSuperview != nil {
            NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(TPKeyboardAvoiding_assignTextDelegateForViewsBeneathView(_:)), object: self)
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_findFirstResponderBeneathView(self)?.resignFirstResponder()
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if !self.focusNextTextField()
        {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        return true
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(TPKeyboardAvoiding_assignTextDelegateForViewsBeneathView(_:)), object: self)

        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(TPKeyboardAvoiding_assignTextDelegateForViewsBeneathView(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
}

private extension TPKeyboardAvoidingCollectionView
{
    func setup()
    {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(TPKeyboardAvoiding_keyboardWillShow(_:)),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame,
                                               object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(TPKeyboardAvoiding_keyboardWillHide(_:)),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide,
                                               object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(scrollToActiveTextField),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.UITextViewTextDidBeginEditing,
                                               object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(scrollToActiveTextField),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditing,
                                               object: nil)
    }
}

// MARK: - ScrollView
class TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView:UIScrollView,UITextFieldDelegate,UITextViewDelegate
{
    override var contentSize:CGSize{
        didSet{
            self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_updateFromContentSizeChange()
        }
    }


    override var frame:CGRect{
        didSet{
            self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_updateContentInset()
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setup()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        setup()
    }

    func contentSizeToFit()
    {
        self.contentSize = self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_calculatedContentSizeFromSubviewFrames()
    }

    func focusNextTextField() ->Bool
    {
        return self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_focusNextTextField()
    }

    @objc func scrollToActiveTextField()
    {
        return self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_scrollToActiveTextField()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setup()
    }

    deinit{
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    override func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {
        super.willMove(toSuperview: newSuperview)
        if newSuperview != nil {
            NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(TPKeyboardAvoiding_assignTextDelegateForViewsBeneathView(_:)), object: self)
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_findFirstResponderBeneathView(self)?.resignFirstResponder()
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if !self.focusNextTextField()
        {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        return true
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(TPKeyboardAvoiding_assignTextDelegateForViewsBeneathView(_:)), object: self)

        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(TPKeyboardAvoiding_assignTextDelegateForViewsBeneathView(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
}

private extension TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView
{
    func setup()
    {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(TPKeyboardAvoiding_keyboardWillShow(_:)),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame,
                                               object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(TPKeyboardAvoiding_keyboardWillHide(_:)),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide,
                                               object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(scrollToActiveTextField),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.UITextViewTextDidBeginEditing,
                                               object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(scrollToActiveTextField),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditing,
                                               object: nil)
    }
}

// MARK: - Process Event
let kCalculatedContentPadding:CGFloat = 10;
let kMinimumScrollOffsetPadding:CGFloat = 20;

extension UIScrollView
{
    @objc func TPKeyboardAvoiding_keyboardWillShow(_ notification:Notification)
    {
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }
        guard let rectNotification = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else
        {
            return
        }

        let keyboardRect = self.convert(rectNotification.cgRectValue , from: nil)
        if keyboardRect.isEmpty
        {
            return
        }

        let state = self.keyboardAvoidingState()

        guard let firstResponder = self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_findFirstResponderBeneathView(self) else { return}
        state.keyboardRect = keyboardRect
        if !state.keyboardVisible
        {
            state.priorInset = self.contentInset
            state.priorScrollIndicatorInsets = self.scrollIndicatorInsets
            state.priorPagingEnabled = self.isPagingEnabled
        }

        state.keyboardVisible = true
        self.isPagingEnabled = false

        if self is TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView
        {
            state.priorContentSize = self.contentSize
            if self.contentSize.equalTo(CGSize.zero)
            {
                self.contentSize = self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_calculatedContentSizeFromSubviewFrames()
            }
        }

        let duration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Float ?? 0.0
        let curve = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? Int ?? 0
        let options = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: UInt(curve))

        UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(duration),
                       delay: 0,
                       options: options,
                       animations: { [weak self]() -> Void in
                        if let actualSelf = self
                        {
                            actualSelf.contentInset = actualSelf.TPKeyboardAvoiding_contentInsetForKeyboard()
                            let viewableHeight = actualSelf.bounds.size.height - actualSelf.contentInset.top - actualSelf.contentInset.bottom
                            let point = CGPoint(x: actualSelf.contentOffset.x, y: actualSelf.TPKeyboardAvoiding_idealOffsetForView(firstResponder, viewAreaHeight: viewableHeight))
                            actualSelf.setContentOffset(point, animated: false)

                            actualSelf.scrollIndicatorInsets = actualSelf.contentInset
                            actualSelf.layoutIfNeeded()
                        }

        }) { (finished) -> Void in

        }
    }

    @objc func TPKeyboardAvoiding_keyboardWillHide(_ notification:Notification)
    {
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }

        guard let rectNotification = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else
        {
            return
        }
        let keyboardRect = self.convert(rectNotification.cgRectValue , from: nil)
        if keyboardRect.isEmpty
        {
            return
        }
        let state = self.keyboardAvoidingState()

        if !state.keyboardVisible
        {
            return
        }
        state.keyboardRect = CGRect.zero
        state.keyboardVisible = false

        let duration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Float ?? 0.0
        let curve = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? Int ?? 0
        let options = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: UInt(curve))

        UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(duration),
                       delay: 0,
                       options: options,
                       animations: { [weak self]() -> Void in
                        if let actualSelf = self
                        {
                            if actualSelf is TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView {
                                actualSelf.contentSize = state.priorContentSize
                                actualSelf.contentInset = state.priorInset
                                actualSelf.scrollIndicatorInsets = state.priorScrollIndicatorInsets
                                actualSelf.isPagingEnabled = state.priorPagingEnabled
                                actualSelf.layoutIfNeeded()
                            }
                        }

        }) { (finished) -> Void in

        }
    }

    func TPKeyboardAvoiding_updateFromContentSizeChange()
    {
        let state = self.keyboardAvoidingState()
        if state.keyboardVisible
        {
            state.priorContentSize = self.contentSize
        }
    }

    func TPKeyboardAvoiding_focusNextTextField() ->Bool
    {
        guard let firstResponder = self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_findFirstResponderBeneathView(self) else { return false}
        guard let view = self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_findNextInputViewAfterView(firstResponder, beneathView: self) else { return false}
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: view, selector: #selector(becomeFirstResponder), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

        return true

    }

    func TPKeyboardAvoiding_scrollToActiveTextField()
    {
        let state = self.keyboardAvoidingState()

        if !state.keyboardVisible { return }

        let visibleSpace = self.bounds.size.height - self.contentInset.top - self.contentInset.bottom

        let idealOffset = CGPoint(x: 0,
                                  y: self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_idealOffsetForView(self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_findFirstResponderBeneathView(self),
                                                                                viewAreaHeight: visibleSpace))

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double((Int64)(0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)) {[weak self] () -> Void in
            self?.setContentOffset(idealOffset, animated: true)
        }
    }

    //Helper
    func TPKeyboardAvoiding_findFirstResponderBeneathView(_ view:UIView) -> UIView?
    {
        for childView in view.subviews
        {
            if childView.responds(to: #selector(getter: isFirstResponder)) && childView.isFirstResponder
            {
                return childView
            }
            let result = TPKeyboardAvoiding_findFirstResponderBeneathView(childView)
            if result != nil
            {
                return result
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func TPKeyboardAvoiding_updateContentInset()
    {
        let state = self.keyboardAvoidingState()
        if state.keyboardVisible
        {
            self.contentInset = self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_contentInsetForKeyboard()
        }
    }

    func TPKeyboardAvoiding_calculatedContentSizeFromSubviewFrames() ->CGSize
    {
        let wasShowingVerticalScrollIndicator = self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator
        let wasShowingHorizontalScrollIndicator = self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator

        self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

        var rect = CGRect.zero

        for view in self.subviews
        {
            rect = rect.union(view.frame)
        }

        rect.size.height += kCalculatedContentPadding
        self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = wasShowingVerticalScrollIndicator
        self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = wasShowingHorizontalScrollIndicator

        return rect.size
    }

    func TPKeyboardAvoiding_idealOffsetForView(_ view:UIView?,viewAreaHeight:CGFloat) -> CGFloat
    {
        let contentSize = self.contentSize

        var offset:CGFloat = 0.0
        let subviewRect =  view != nil ? view!.convert(view!.bounds, to: self) : CGRect.zero

        var padding = (viewAreaHeight - subviewRect.height)/2
        if padding < kMinimumScrollOffsetPadding
        {
            padding = kMinimumScrollOffsetPadding
        }

        offset = subviewRect.origin.y - padding - self.contentInset.top

        if offset > (contentSize.height - viewAreaHeight)
        {
            offset = contentSize.height - viewAreaHeight
        }

        if offset < -self.contentInset.top
        {
            offset = -self.contentInset.top
        }

        return offset
    }

    func TPKeyboardAvoiding_contentInsetForKeyboard() -> UIEdgeInsets
    {
        let state = self.keyboardAvoidingState()
        var newInset = self.contentInset;

        let keyboardRect = state.keyboardRect
        newInset.bottom = keyboardRect.size.height - max(keyboardRect.maxY - self.bounds.maxY, 0)

        return newInset

    }

    func TPKeyboardAvoiding_viewIsValidKeyViewCandidate(_ view:UIView)->Bool
    {
        if view.isHidden || !view.isUserInteractionEnabled {return false}

        if view is UITextField
        {
            if (view as! UITextField).isEnabled {return true}
        }

        if view is UITextView
        {
            if (view as! UITextView).isEditable {return true}
        }

        return false
    }

    func TPKeyboardAvoiding_findNextInputViewAfterView(_ priorView:UIView,beneathView view:UIView, candidateView bestCandidate: inout UIView?)
    {
        let priorFrame = self.convert(priorView.frame, to: priorView.superview)
        let candidateFrame = bestCandidate == nil ? CGRect.zero : self.convert(bestCandidate!.frame, to: bestCandidate!.superview)

        var bestCandidateHeuristic = -sqrt(candidateFrame.origin.x*candidateFrame.origin.x + candidateFrame.origin.y*candidateFrame.origin.y) + ( Float(fabs(candidateFrame.minY - priorFrame.minY))<Float.ulpOfOne ? 1e6 : 0)

        for childView in view.subviews
        {
            if TPKeyboardAvoiding_viewIsValidKeyViewCandidate(childView)
            {
                let frame = self.convert(childView.frame, to: view)
                let heuristic = -sqrt(frame.origin.x*frame.origin.x + frame.origin.y*frame.origin.y)
                    + (Float(fabs(frame.minY - priorFrame.minY)) < Float.ulpOfOne ? 1e6 : 0)

                if childView != priorView && (Float(fabs(frame.minY - priorFrame.minY)) < Float.ulpOfOne
                    && frame.minX > priorFrame.minX
                    || frame.minY > priorFrame.minY)
                    && (bestCandidate == nil || heuristic > bestCandidateHeuristic)
                {
                    bestCandidate = childView
                    bestCandidateHeuristic = heuristic
                }
            }else
            {
                self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_findNextInputViewAfterView(priorView, beneathView: view, candidateView: &bestCandidate)
            }
        }
    }

    func TPKeyboardAvoiding_findNextInputViewAfterView(_ priorView:UIView,beneathView view:UIView) ->UIView?
    {
        var candidate:UIView?
        self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_findNextInputViewAfterView(priorView, beneathView: view, candidateView: &candidate)
        return candidate
    }


    @objc func TPKeyboardAvoiding_assignTextDelegateForViewsBeneathView(_ obj: AnyObject)
    {
        func processWithView(_ view: UIView) {
            for childView in view.subviews
            {
                if childView is UITextField || childView is UITextView
                {
                    self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_initializeView(childView)
                }else
                {
                    self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_assignTextDelegateForViewsBeneathView(childView)
                }
            }
        }

        if let timer = obj as? Timer, let view = timer.userInfo as? UIView {
            processWithView(view)
        }
        else if let view = obj as? UIView {
            processWithView(view)
        }
    }

    func TPKeyboardAvoiding_initializeView(_ view:UIView)
    {
        if let textField = view as? UITextField,
            let delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate, textField.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyType.default &&
            textField.delegate !== delegate
        {
            textField.delegate = delegate
            let otherView = self.TPKeyboardAvoiding_findNextInputViewAfterView(view, beneathView: self)
            textField.returnKeyType = otherView != nil ? .next : .done

        }
    }

    func keyboardAvoidingState()->TPKeyboardAvoidingState
    {
        var state = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeysKeyboard.DescriptiveName) as? TPKeyboardAvoidingState
        if state == nil
        {
            state = TPKeyboardAvoidingState()
            self.state = state
        }

        return self.state!
    }

}

// MARK: - Internal object observer
internal class TPKeyboardAvoidingState:NSObject
{
    var priorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    var priorScrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero

    var keyboardVisible = false
    var keyboardRect = CGRect.zero
    var priorContentSize = CGSize.zero

    var priorPagingEnabled = false
}

internal extension UIScrollView
{
    fileprivate struct AssociatedKeysKeyboard {
        static var DescriptiveName = "KeyBoard_DescriptiveName"
    }

    var state:TPKeyboardAvoidingState?{
        get{
            let optionalObject:AnyObject? = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeysKeyboard.DescriptiveName) as AnyObject?
            if let object:AnyObject = optionalObject {
                return object as? TPKeyboardAvoidingState
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        set{
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeysKeyboard.DescriptiveName, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the keyboard height(as it's different for some of the devices) and move the view by that size.

Add these 2 lines to your viewDidLoad method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
```

Then add these 2 methods.

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
       let keyboardSize = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect {
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height
        self.view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardHeight
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
     self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just enclose your textbox inside a view and then override inputAccessoryView returning the view. 
Important: Your view should be created programmatically. Do not use @IBOutlets.

```
 override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    get {
        return newlyProgramaticallyCreatedView
    }}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're like me, using Autolayout and not getting the keyboard when running the App on a simulator. This might be because Apple make you use the keyboard of you're computer as first Keyboard.

To make the keyboard from the device appear :

<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

Sounds stupid but I would have loved to find this answer 3 hours ago :)

Answer (score -2):

In Swift 4.0 -

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        animateViewMoving(up: true, moveValue: 100)
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        animateViewMoving(up: false, moveValue: 100)
    }
    func animateViewMoving (up:Bool, moveValue :CGFloat){
        let movementDuration:TimeInterval = 0.3
        let movement:CGFloat = ( up ? -moveValue : moveValue)
        UIView.beginAnimations( "animateView", context: nil)
        UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration ) 
        self.view.frame = self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: movement)
        UIView.commitAnimations()
    }
```