# Move textfield when keyboard pops up using auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, autolayout

I have this code that can push everything up in my view controller when the keyboard displays. However, it doesn't work with auto layout. Can I adapt this code to work with my constraints or is there a better method to move textfields and buttons up so that the keyboard doesn't hide them? Thanks.

```
    func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y -= 150
}
func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y += 150
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693130/move-textfield-when-keyboard-appears-swift

Comment: i looked at that but I am confused with the bottom space to superview constraint. Do i set that for every textfield and button I have? Do I just set it for the bottommost element?

Comment: please see this extension http://stackoverflow.com/a/36808722/3472073 it should help you