# ScrollView with Tab bar

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a to implement something similar to a chat.

So I thought I will add a scrollview then a table view then a view for textfield and send button then on top of it a tableview.

I also have a tabbar on bottom

Is this the right approach. I also wanted to bring the keyboard up and move the text box upwards

[image]

[image]

The images is not containing a scroll view because when ever i put a scroll view its screws me up

Additionally I also want to know how to increase the size of the rows depending on the chat message.
just a crude drawing 
[image]

this is what I have achieved so far
[image]
[image]

I am not able to increase the size of the label according to the data, nor I am able to bring the textfield up when the keyboard is showing. :(

Comment: when you say 'is this the right approach' - the right approach for what? and what does 'it screws me up' mean?

Comment: I saw some tutorials saying I need a scrollview for moving the textfield up.

Comment: perhaps you could start with a picture of what you're trying to achieve then we can advise on the best way to achieve it?

Comment: updated in my question

Comment: @CharlesA I have updated the question with the screenshots from the phone please take a look and see if you can help me

Comment: @CharlesA I have got what I was looking for thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got my answer, here is my set up and my output.
Thanks to @Isuru for his answer in [Move textfield when keyboard appears swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693130/move-textfield-when-keyboard-appears-swift/25693748)
and @esthepiking for helping me out

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

UITableView already inherits from, and contains a UIScrollView so you don't need to add a scroll view yourself, and it would probably cause problems, as I assume is the case from what you have described.

To have the cells adjust automatically, I would check out this tutorial https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/ios-8-tutorial-series-auto-sizing-table-cells. It provides lots of details on how and why it works.

For the message bar on the bottom, the way I've done it in the past, is to add the view with the text field and send button to a view (I'll call it the message view) the main view stuck to the bottom, then also set that message view as the input accessory on the text field, so when the text field starts editing, the view will be snapped to the top of the keyboard automatically. I can't quite tell how you have constrained the message view in your picture, but make sure that the bottom of the table view is not constrained to the top of the message view. You want the message view to be floating on top, then the table view can either be constrained the height of the message view from the bottom, or you can set the content inset to push content above the message view.

Comment: if you could see my screenshot once more maybe you could help me guide in right way. And the link you have provided is also not accessible