# Swift move view when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield

I have six UITextFields in my view and I want to decide whether the view has to move or not. How can I check which TextField is selected before moving my view?

Thats my Code for showing the keyboard and moving the view:

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
            if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height - 85
            }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
            if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
                self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height - 85
            }
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693130/move-textfield-when-keyboard-appears-swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know which `UITextField` is selected, you can use `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and `textFieldDidEndEditing`

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {
    currentSelectedTextField = textField
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField!) {
    currentSelectedTextField = nil
}
```

For your reference about how to manage keyboard when selecting a `UITextField`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html