# How do I make a keyboard push the view up when it comes on screen? Xcode Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, text, keyboard

So I have a view with a text field in it, but the text field is at the bottom. When I click the keyboard, it pops up and covers the text field, this is my problem. I was wondering if it is at all possible to push the rest of the view up when a keyboard comes up?

Comment: I can see at least 4 similar questions in the "Related" section. Please explain what you tried and why/how it did not work.

Answer (score 7):

You can register your view controller to be notified when the keyboard is about to be shown, then you push your view up.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var keyboardAdjusted = false
var lastKeyboardOffset: CGFloat = 0.0

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if keyboardAdjusted == false {
        lastKeyboardOffset = getKeyboardHeight(notification)
        view.frame.origin.y -= lastKeyboardOffset
        keyboardAdjusted = true
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if keyboardAdjusted == true {
        view.frame.origin.y += lastKeyboardOffset
        keyboardAdjusted = false
    }
}

func getKeyboardHeight(notification: NSNotification) -> CGFloat {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo
    let keyboardSize = userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
    return keyboardSize.CGRectValue().height
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this tutorial [Move UITextField so keyboard does not hide it](http://www.buildsucceeded.com/2014/swift-move-uitextfield-so-keyboard-does-not-hide-it-ios-8-xcode-6-swift/)

You will find demo for this [here](https://github.com/ttippin84/VBResponsiveTextFieldViewController)

Or you can check the answer of this stackoverflow [Move textfield when keyboard appears swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693130/move-textfield-when-keyboard-appears-swift)

Best answer there is to manage by updating bottom constraint like this

```
func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {
     var info = notification.userInfo!
     var keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

     UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
       self.bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height + 20
  })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should put text field into `UIScrollView` and adjust its `contentInset` on `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`.

Read this help page: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7