# How can I add textfield on keyboard in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, keyboard

In my Purpose, I want to **custom keyboard** by **adding textfield on the keyboard look like Facebook app on iOS**. when you tap on comment button it will appear the keyboard on also have textfield above that. 
Do you have any keyword or solution on that problem?. I am youngest with swift and write in native language. If you do not clear with my question please comment.
Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but it seems like you want a textfield just above the keyboard. For that you can add a TextField on the bottom of a view and make it move accordingly whenever the keyboard appears. Check this out: [Move textfield when keyboard appears swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693130/move-textfield-when-keyboard-appears-swift)

Comment: It's wrong that I want. The textfield on the textfield. did you used to play Facebook by iOS app?.. when you tap a comment button it will  appear like that I want. thank for answer

Comment: You can accomplish the same by adding a textfield on the bottom of the screen and set textfield.becomeFirstResponder() on viewDidLoad. Then your app would need to listen to UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification to change the textfield position.