# Fit with open keyboard Swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I am a beginner in Swift and I have a PopUp on a screen that lists some items, I would like to know how I do when to open the keyboard the PopUp resize, without the keyboard overlapping it. Thanks, I hope someone can help. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJTG0.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use notification to get event when keyboard opens or hides.
In that appropriate event, you can resize popup screen.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27135992/8358956 this answer can be helpful to you.