# keyboard covering the textfields in subview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I have a view which contains 4 textfields and a button .. this view is not the main view .. the problem is that the keyboard covers the textfields down and the button!

i tried this code but its not working:

```
   // Move the text field in a pretty animation!
func moveTextField(_ textField: UITextField, moveDistance: Int, up: Bool) {
    let moveDuration = 0.3
    let movement: CGFloat = CGFloat(up ? moveDistance : -moveDistance)
    if textField.tag>=2{
        UIView.beginAnimations("animateTextField", context: nil)
        UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(moveDuration)
        self.view.frame = self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: movement)
        UIView.commitAnimations()}
}
```

and i have set the tag numbers for them from 0 to 4...

and i have set the delegate in viewDidLoad:

```
    fname.delegate=self
    email.delegate=self
    mobile1.delegate=self
    mobile2.delegate=self
```

but this didn't work still the keyboard will cover the textfields down and the button! why? and how to solve it?

**UPDATE**:

I think i figured out the problem ... i tried this:

```
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidChangeFrame, object: nil)
}
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidChangeFrame, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillChange(notification: Notification){

    guard let keyboardRect = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else{
        return
    }
    if activeTF.tag >= 2 {
    if notification.name == Notification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow || notification.name == Notification.Name.UIKeyboardDidChangeFrame {

        view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardRect.height
   }else{
        view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
}
}
```

with:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true

}
```

both funcs works perfectly... but when i change it to:

```
  func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{

    // Try to find next responder
    if let nextField = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1) as? UITextField {
        nextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else {
        // Not found, so remove keyboard.
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    //do not add a line break
    return false
}
```

only the maketextfieldreturn will work and keyboardwillchange will not work! Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a UITextField move up when the keyboard is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-can-i-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-the-keyboard-is-present)

Comment: @the4kman this is objective-c ....

Comment: This question is asked so many times before, you can easily find solution if you try.

Comment: @mrs.tat There are lots of Swift answers under that question.

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693130/move-textfield-when-keyboard-appears-swift

Comment: Or just use a third party lib, like IQKeyboardManagerSwift

Comment: @Kuldeep i tried many but none worked! for example the link you referred to .. didn't work :(

Comment: @mrs.tat follow this: https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: @Kuldeep can't i do it without a library?

Comment: yes you can do it without library, you can use UIKeyBoardNotification.

Comment: @Kuldeep tried it and didn't work also T_T

Comment: @mrs.tat, what you tried, update your question with your tried code.

Comment: @Kuldeep updated .. actually i tried a lot more but deleted the code cuz they are useless...

Comment: @Kuldeep can you check my update please

Comment: @the4kman can you check my update please