# How can I pass multiple parameters to Swift #selector?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to pass ina second parameter to a selector function that comes from another function:

```
func bindToKeyboardNew(constraint: NSLayoutConstraint) { // <- this parameter 
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:constraint:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification, constraint: NSLayoutConstraint) // <- To This selector {

}
```

Comment: You can't. You need another way to access the constraint in the `keyboardWillShow` function.

Comment: What is the workaround there? I'm trying to develop an extension to bind a view to keyboard very easily ;(

Comment: you can bind view in userInfo dict in notification of selector

Comment: @abu ul Hassan it's like normal binding, it doesn't work properly

Comment: well it should work properly, matter is sending an object with valid approach and i think there is no more valid way to pass any object  except userInfo dict.

Answer (score 3):

The easier way you can pass data is creating a custom class.
Example I need pass data through `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

First, create a custom `UITapGestureRecognizer` and define a instance which is your data

```
class CustomTapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer {
    var data: YourData
}
```

```
let tapGesture = CustomTapGesture(target: self, action: #selector(tapGesture(_:)))
tapGesture.data = yourData
yourView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

**#selector** function

```
@objc func tap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let sender = sender as? CustomTapGesture {
       yourData = sender.data
       // do something with your data
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand but what is it in my case with NotificattionCenter and NSNotification they're two different Things

Comment: U can create a custom class and instance of `NotificattionCenter` and `NSNotification` are your data.

Comment: ```class Custom {
    var instance1: NotificattionCenter?
    var instance2: NSNotification?
}```

Answer (score 0):

As @rmaddy mentioned in the comment this **cannot be done** the way you're asking for.

In this part

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:constraint:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
```

you have **no control** over how exactly the selector is sent (and with what args).

UIKit **internally** in its private implementation does something like this (*let's ignore for a second that its implementation isn't really Swift, that's not important here*):

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification), object: uiwindow, userInfo: systemUserInfoForKeyboardShow)
```

What it means the selector is already sent and there's **no way** to add something extra to optional userInfo (you could do that if the `.post(...)` did happen in your code, but that's **not** the case here).

You need an **alternative way** to access your current `NSLayoutConstraint` object inside the keyboard selector show/hide handlers. Maybe it should be a property in your `ViewController` , maybe some state of your `AppDelegate` or maybe something completely different, it's impossible to tell not knowing rest of your code.

EDIT: As per your added comment I'd assume that you have something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var constraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
}
```

If so you can simply access the constraint in your selector handler inside the VC:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var constraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification) {
       //do something with the constraint 
       print(constraint)
    }
}
```

There's also a dedicated `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` perhaps it could provide you with what you need out of the box. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27135992/5329717)

Comment: Its in my Viewcontroller

Comment: I know what. But That's not what I want. I wanted a dedicated class for that so I don't have to put that chunk of code in it. But I found a solution already(look at my other question). Thanks anyway.