# Move textview of variable height when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

I've a VC with few views above textfield and a button below text view contained inside scroll view. I'm trying to move textview up when keyboard is shown but I can't get it working correctly.

Textview height <=100 in IB. I'm adjusting textview height as we type in it up to max 120 then it scrolls.

I've read it and tried most of solution provided on [Move textfield when keyboard appears swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693130/move-textfield-when-keyboard-appears-swift)

The problem I'm facing is bottom constraints, if I set it then my textview stretches in height when it loads and then it breaks textview height adjustment during typing. And I can't find any working solution without setting bottom constraints.

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add fixed text view height and set bottom constraints to greater than or equal to.