# Smooth animation in keyboardWillShow doesn't work with UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview, uistackview

**Solution which worked for me**

After struggling for days I finally manage to find the fix for view animation issue. For me **keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification** worked. The solution is discussed in the following thread:

[Move textfield when keyboard appears swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693130/move-textfield-when-keyboard-appears-swift/27855636)

[image: Gif]

I've a bunch of views embedded inside stack view along with text view. I've given text view height of <= 120. In keyboardWillShow view doesn't animate despite adding code as required. I've played with duration value but it's all same result. I was wondering if it's due to text view? How to fix it?

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification) {

    guard let keyboardValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }

    let keyboardScreenEndFrame = keyboardValue.cgRectValue
    let keyboardFrame = view.convert(keyboardScreenEndFrame, from: view.window)

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardFrame.height - view.safeAreaInsets.bottom, right: 0)
    } else {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardFrame.height, right: 0)
    }

    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = scrollView.contentInset

    let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentSize.height + keyboardFrame.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height)
    scrollView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

===

```
   extension FirstViewController: UITextViewDelegate {

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

        let estimatedSize = textView.sizeThatFits(textView.frame.size)

        if estimatedSize.height > textViewMaxHeight {
            if estimatedSize.height - textViewMaxHeight < textView.font!.lineHeight && !didExpandTextView {

                didExpandTextView = true

                var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: self.savedKbHeight, right: 0.0)

                if let v = self.tabBarController?.tabBar {
                    contentInset.bottom -= v.frame.height
                }

                scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
                scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInset

                if textView.isFirstResponder {
                    let fr = textView.frame
                    scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(fr, animated: false)
                }
            }

            textView.isScrollEnabled = true
            textView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true

        } else {
            if let lineHeight = textView.font?.lineHeight, Int(estimatedSize.height / lineHeight) != numberOfLines {
                numberOfLines = Int(estimatedSize.height / textView.font!.lineHeight)

                var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: self.savedKbHeight, right: 0.0)

                print("contentInset: \(contentInset)")
                scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
                scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInset

                if textView.isFirstResponder {
                    let fr = textView.frame
                    scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(fr, animated: false)
                }

                didExpandTextView = false
            }

            textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        }
    }

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Comment: Quick test indicates a couple problems with this code... Even with the animation you posted, it appears the scroll content is pushed higher than necessary. Also, when tapping into either text field while the keyboard is showing pushes the text field up and out-of-frame. (I'm surprised you're not using the keyboard code I gave you for this layout.)

Comment: I've already tried your code, it's still same result. With your code both issues, constraints and animation, are showing same problem as my code above. Please try inserting a textview and restricting it's height to <=120, disable scrolling in textview from IB and see the outcome.

Comment: Here is link showing the outcome using your code. https://imgur.com/a/EklKnaw

Comment: If you're still having trouble with this, I think the issue may be due to the "auto-vertical-centering" that you're doing. You may need to take a different approach to that.

Comment: I'm still having trouble. I didn't get what you meant by auto-vertical-centering. Can you elaborate that with code?

Comment: From previous questions, your using a stack view and constraints to keep the "overall content" vertically centered. Take a look at my updated GitHub repo for another approach... it may or may not be smooth enough: https://github.com/DonMag/CenteredScroll

Comment: Thanks again for taking time to fix this. It seems to be working. I'll try it in my project, will update later.

Comment: I've tried your solution which works fine if textview height is limited. However in my project I need to expand textview height to max 120 and after that enable scrolling in textview. I've some code to handle scrolling of textview in textViewDidChange which makes views jump up and down with expanding text view height. Would you be able to look into it? I'll update textViewDidChange code in question.

Comment: I've updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```swift
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

        let estimatedSize = textView.sizeThatFits(textView.frame.size)

        textView.isScrollEnabled = estimatedSize.height > textViewMaxHeight

        if !textView.isScrollEnabled {
            let maxBottom = self.view.frame.height - self.savedKbHeight

            // Use following line if you have Extended Edges set
            // let maxBottom = self.view.frame.height - self.savedKbHeight - topLayoutGuide.length - bottomLayoutGuide.length

            var r = self.textView.frame
            r.size.height = estimatedSize.height
            let tvBottom = self.scrollView.convert(r, to: self.view).maxX
            if tvBottom > maxBottom {
                self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(r, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Edit** *Note:* This is not intended to be **Production Ready** code. There are many things that affect layout / positioning, and there is no guarantee that just "dropping this in" will work in all situations.

Comment: Thanks, much better now. The last issue is that when return key is hit, views jump and then adjusts itself. See this https://imgur.com/a/iFqlPJi How do we fix this one?

Comment: @Raymond - take a fresh look at my GitHub repo: https://github.com/DonMag/CenteredScroll ... second tab (yellow/orange background) has `textViewDidChange()` implemented, and I'm not seeing what you're seeing.

Comment: that's correct, it doesn't have that bug however there is another bug in this one. It hides and pushes down login button after every return. Can we keep the login button showing all the time while text view expands and pushes views up with new line?

Comment: @Raymond - *"Can we keep the login button showing..."* -- sure. Use the button frame instead of the text view frame.

Comment: I wish I could fix it. I tried with var r = self.loginButton.frame in textViewDidChange but it's doing some funny push up with views. Could you please do it in the code. I'm still struggling to understanding this whole scrolling stuff.

Comment: @Raymond - I updated my GitHub repo... first tab example keeps login button showing. As a side note: I don't want this to sound bad, but Stack Overflow is not a "write my code for me" site. Ask a question... if it is answered, mark the answer Accepted and move on. I've answered several of your questions now with your response being *"oh, but now I want to do [this]"*. The more you do that, the less likely people will be willing to offer help.

Comment: It didn't work, thanks anyways I think you have already done too much for me. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Raymond - curious... here's recording when I run it: https://imgur.com/a/rRHTMoB

Comment: It pushes down login button when text view expand to show scroll. Let's leave it. I'll try to figure out myself or I'll never learn.

Comment: @Raymond - updated my GitHub repo again... give it one more try.

Comment: Just wanted to add that if Extended Edges are enabled then this will break scroll view when you type into text view. Wasted 2 days of time to figure out that. To fix this issue we need to use topLayoutGuide.length & bottomLayoutGuide.length in height calculations. let maxBottom = self.view.frame.height - self.savedKbHeight - topLayoutGuide.length - bottomLayoutGuide.length