# Attaching UIView (messaybox) to keyboard manager so the view moves with the keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, view, keyboard

Has anyone had this problem before? message input bar is not staying attached to keyboard as I drag view down. Anyone know how to attach the message input bar view to the keyboard so when the keyboard moves, the input bar moves with it? [click here for image of bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRVAh.png)

Comment: You can find many solutions from here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693130/move-textfield-when-keyboard-appears-swift

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask]. Your first step should be some searching... you'll find many, many examples -- likely, one that fits your needs.