# How to animate a UIView with constraints in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uiviewanimation

In my contrived example, I have the following single view:

[image]

As you can see, it consists of a few simple constraints:

1. Align horizontal and vertical centers,
2. Height (set to a constant)
3. Leading and trailing spaces (set to constant)

What I'm seeking to achieve is to have this redish/pinkish view "come in" from the top. Traditionally, in a constraint-less world, I would simply modify the frame inside of `UIView.animateWithDuration`, however I'm not sure how I do the similar in a constraint world.

**To reiterate my question, how can I make my view start out of scene and animate the view flying in from the top?**

I've considered animating the vertical centers constraint (and subsequently calling `layoutIfNeeded`), but it's not achieving the desired effect.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I animate constraint changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622424/how-do-i-animate-constraint-changes)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

What you can do is to add the following code in your `viewDidAppear` method. You firstly make a `IBOutlet` property of your view's center Y constraint, and then change its constant value.

```
self.centerYConstraint.constant = 500.0
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

UIView.animateWithDuration(Double(0.5), animations: {
        self.centerYConstraint.constant = 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
```

Comment: Using a constant doesn't mean that you have centered the view at all. If you rotate the device you've lost your view.

Comment: Guys,  self.view.layoutIfNeeded() is the key

Comment: @DanielGalasko, you can reverse first and second item to go from -500 to 0

Comment: @wyu not entirely sure that makes sense in regards to what I am implying? I have already answered this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/27417189/1652402

Comment: Good solutions.

Answer (score 15):

What you want is in fact rather simple, and I will detail how it should be done without messing with priorities or funky constants. This way we can get an animation that will work on any screen size.

The TL;DR is that you need to configure your constraints and then call layoutIfNeeded inside your animation block to animate the changes. For more [see this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622424/how-do-i-animate-constraint-changes).

So we need two sets of constraints for hiding and showing the view. In `viewDidLoad` the view will be hidden, and then in `viewDidAppear` or wherever we want that view to slide in.

### Storyboard/XIB Setup

So the first thing is to configure the constraints that won't be changing in IB (or code, whichever you are comfortable with). Namely; the height of the red view, and its leading and trailing space to the container. So your constraints might look like this (**note:** I haven't set a width constraint but let the leading and trailing spaces define the width):

[image: Constraints]

Now you will see that IB will warn you that there is no constraint configured for the Y position of your view (hence the red dotted lines)

[image: View with warnings]

You can now add the top space to container constraint and set it as a placeholder constraint (checkbox that says "remove at build time"). We do this because we want to control where the view is programatically.

[image]

This means that this constraint will not exist once the view is loaded but serves to remove all your warnings as you are telling IB that you know how to deal with this constraint when the view is loaded.

### Coding Time

Now we need a method to hide the view, a method to show the view. For this we are going to store the Y positioning constraint on the view and then animate it. Our viewController could look like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var redView: UIView!
var redViewYPositionConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.hideRedViewAnimated(false)
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.showRedViewAnimated(true)
}
```

#### Hiding

Our method to hide the view can simply remove the position constraint and then add one with the red views bottom equal to the view controller's view top:

```
func hideRedViewAnimated(animated: Bool) {
    //remove current constraint
    self.removeRedViewYPositionConstraint()
    let hideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.redView,
        attribute: .Bottom,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: self.view,
        attribute: .Top,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0)
    self.redViewYPositionConstraint = hideConstraint
    self.view.addConstraint(hideConstraint)
    //animate changes
    self.performConstraintLayout(animated: animated)
}
```

#### Showing

Similarly our show constraint will move the view's center Y to the controllers center Y:

```
func showRedViewAnimated(animated: Bool) {
    //remove current constraint
    self.removeRedViewYPositionConstraint()
    let centerYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.redView,
        attribute: .CenterY,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: self.view,
        attribute: .CenterY,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0)
    self.redViewYPositionConstraint = centerYConstraint
    self.view.addConstraint(centerYConstraint)
    //animate changes
    self.performConstraintLayout(animated: animated)
}
```

#### Convenience Methods

For completeness the convenience methods I have used look like this:

```
func performConstraintLayout(animated animated: Bool) {
    if animated == true {
          UIView.animateWithDuration(1,
          delay: 0,
          usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5,
          initialSpringVelocity: 0.6,
          options: .BeginFromCurrentState,
          animations: { () -> Void in
             self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
          }, completion: nil)
     } else {
          self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
     }
}

func removeRedViewYPositionConstraint() {
    if redViewYPositionConstraint != nil {
        self.view.removeConstraint(self.redViewYPositionConstraint!)
        self.redViewYPositionConstraint = nil
    }
}
```

You can also check if the red view is visible by using some CGRect math:

```
func isRedViewVisible() -> Bool {
    return CGRectContainsPoint(self.view.bounds, self.redView.frame.origin)
}
```

Comment: Fantastic answer. Since the version of iOS question that was current back in 2014 when this question was answered, layout anchors (such as UIView.anchorTop, .anchorBottom, .anchorLeading, .anchorTrailing, .anchorWidth, .anchorHeight, .centerXanchor, .centerYanchor....) are much more concise and easy to use  programmatically.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // red view
    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
    //  vertical align contraint
    @IBOutlet weak var verticalConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        verticalConstraint.constant = (myView.bounds.height + self.view.bounds.height)/2
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
            self.verticalConstraint.constant = 0
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

}
```

Be careful about `firstItem` and `secondItem` order in the constraint. The above code assumes Superview is the `firstItem`:

[image: screenshot]

---

Alternative way is to define **two** constraints:

- **Center Y Alignment constraint** (Superview.CenterY == View.CenterY) priority = 750
- **Vertical Space Constraint** (SuperView.Top == View.Bottom) priority = 500

[image: screenshot]

And adjust the **priority** to determine which contraint should be adopted.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //  vertical align contraint
    @IBOutlet weak var centerYConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        centerYConstraint.priority = 250
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
            self.centerYConstraint.priority = 750
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Priorities is not strictly speaking the best means of achieving this as you are hoping that the layout system won't enforce the center constraint because of its lower priority. You should rather configure the constraints properly for hiding and showing the view

Answer (score 10):

For anyone looking for simple animation like the request:

> For the slide up animation you need to use [...] the
>   **CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x, y)**.
>
> The reason is that for a slide up animation you need first move the
>   view off screen and then bring it back to its original position. So in
>   your viewDidLoad just use:
>
> ```
> yourView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 500)
> ```
>
> This moves the view off screen, in this case at the bottom. Now in the
>   **viewDidAppear** you can show your view with:
>
> ```
> UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5,
> initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: [], animations: {
>         self.yourView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)
>     }, completion: nil)
> ```

With these lines you can add the constraints that you want on your UIView and place it where you need in your ViewController.

Comment: Can you add some content from your link?

Comment: sure wait just some minutes!

Comment: This is nice animation

Answer (score 5):

For me the best way for animate **Swift 3 & 4**

```
self.constraint.constant = -150

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.45) { [weak self] in
    self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```