# A navigator menu slide in from right

Tags: ios, swift, menu, slide, navigator

This is code for navigator menu:

```
    let menuIconImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "menu_icon"))
    menuIconImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    menuIconImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 35, y: 30, width: 35, height: 30)
    menuIconImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    self.view.addSubview(menuIconImageView)
```

How do I make a menu slide in from right on a click?

Answer (score 0):

Create a width constraint for your `menuIconImageView`and set it to `0` for it's initial value. Once you click on the button set the width value to `35` then animate with `UIView.animate(withDuration:){ view.layoutIfNeeded() }`. Also make sure that you have a trailing constraint to superView and the value is set to `0` for your `menuIconImageView`.

You can check below thread for code examples

[How to animate a UIView with constraints in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27371935/how-to-animate-a-uiview-with-constraints-in-swift)