# How to animate cross dissolve a view when added as a subview?

Tags: ios, swift

I am adding a view as a subview in a `UIViewController` at the bottom of the current view. I am able to do fade animation using alpha, but I wanted to show it like slide in like a keyboard popup.

```
let popup: UIView = ..
popup.alpha = 0.0
self.view.addSubView(popup)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
    popup.alpha = 1.0
}) { _ in
}
```

How to animate this?

Comment: Cross dissolve is a fade in/out like you have already. You want to animate the view in from off the bottom of the screen to its final location?

Comment: No a cross dissolve is not the same as a fade in.  You need to also fade out the view underneath.

Comment: @Daniel Storm: Yes, similar to when a keyboard popup. The keyboard slides in from the bottom and slides out. I am looking for a similar animation.

Comment: @JoshHomann there’s no mention of another view in this question.

Comment: @DanielStorm it clearly says the view is being added over the current view controller.

Comment: @jsloop you’ll want to change your views frame in that animation block also then. Or if you’re using auto layout, it’s constraints.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to animate a UIView with constraints in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27371935/how-to-animate-a-uiview-with-constraints-in-swift)

Comment: I think the question is inaccurate.  You already have a sort of cross dissolve, right?  You're looking for a slide-in effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update the frame, but I like to animate using the transform, that way you can still use constraints and don't have to mess with them.

```
let popup: UIView = ..
popup.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: popup.bounds.height)
self.view.addSubView(popup)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
    popup.transform = .identity
}) { _ in
}
```

Assuming the view is at the bottom of the screen, you translate the view down by an amount equal to its height, and then animate the transform back to it's identity, which is the original position.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a cross-fade by merely adding a subview, try `UIView.transition(with:duration:options:animations:completion:)`  Add your view during the animation block.

A quick playground:

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 20)
        label.text = "Hello World!"
        label.textColor = .black

        view.addSubview(label)
        self.view = view
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let orangeView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)))

        orangeView.backgroundColor = .orange
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(300)) {
            UIView.transition(with: self.view, duration: 0.6, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                self.view.addSubview(orangeView)
            }) { _ in

            }

        }
    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```