# animateWithDuration in UITableViewCell's setSelected method has no effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint, animatewithduration

I'm trying a simple animation for selection/deselection of a UITableViewCell like this:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

        tabConstraint.constant = selected ? 40 : 20;

    } completion:nil];
}
```

The code inside the animations block will be called, but it's not animating. Everything works fine, but there's not any animation at all. How could I make the cell selection animated?

Comment: What do you have inside the //code part? You just commented out the most important part of the entire snippet.

Comment: I just set a constraint. Updated the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you update a autolayout constraint, you have to call layoutIfNeeded,

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {


    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

        tabConstraint.constant = selected ? 40 : 20;
        [self layoutIfNeeded];

    } completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can format your code with 4 spaces or the {} button.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `layoutIfNeeded` in your `animations` block. Check out the accepted answer on this question for more details: [How do I animate constraint changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12622424)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `layoutIfNeeded()` inside the animation block :-)

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    tabConstraint.constant = selected ? 40 : 20;
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        whateverTabYouHaveHere.layoutIfNeeded()
    } completion:nil];
}
```