# Swift layoutIfNeeded within animateWithDuration very slow

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, animatewithduration

I am updating a `UIView` with `layoutIfNeeded` within an `animateWithDuration` block, but the duration is taking much longer than what I have coded. Here is the code:

```
func showInfoView() {
    self.hintConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.height - (self.infoView.frame.height + 260)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    infoView.hidden = false
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

The animation is taking longer than 0.2 seconds. Even if I set the duration time to 0, which should make the code layout the view without animating, the animation still occurs. Does `layoutIfNeeded` automatically have a duration when it's within the `animateWithDuration` block? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Is there a reason why you change a constraint, **layout the view**, change a view property, then layout the view again (in the animation block)?  You should be able to change the constraint, call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints,` change the view property, then layout the view in the animation, saving you one (no-op) layout iteration.

Comment: I read somewhere, but I can't find where right now, that I should perform layoutIfNeeded before the animate with duration just in case anythings needs to be updated. If I remove that statement, my problem still occurs.

Comment: [Found this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12664093/4473451), it looks like you layoutIfNeeded before you change the constraint. Give that a try.

Comment: For some reason, that did the trick. Could you post an answer so I could accept?