# Update some subviews without updating all of them

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uilabel

I have a `UIViewController` with several different `UIView` subviews in it. I manually change the size, scale and position of each one when a certain action is called by the user. I would like to update the text in one of the `UILabel`s (one of the subviews) but every time I do, all the subviews revert back to their original sizes and locations that the storyboard calls for. Is there a way to prevent this from happening, i.e. only changing the text without reverting back to the old measurements?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to update the text in one of the UILabels (one of the subviews) but every time I do, all the subviews revert back to their original sizes and locations that the storyboard calls for. Is there a way to prevent this from happening, i.e. only changing the text without reverting back to the old measurements?

The problem is that you changed the sizes and locations of the subviews by setting their `frame` properties. You must *not* do that to a view that is under the control of auto layout! If you do, exactly this thing will happen: when layout time comes, the auto layout constraints are enforced and the views jump back to what you call the sizes and locations that the storyboard calls for. And setting the label text does cause layout time to happen.

Instead, to change the sizes and locations of the subviews, change their constraints! (Or, change their frames and *then* change their constraints to match.) That way, when layout time comes, nothing will happen: the constraints will match the current sizes and locations of the subviews.

Comment: To animate constraint changes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622424/how-do-i-animate-constraint-changes