# How to do animation using autolayout in ease in ease out fashion for all screen sizes of iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

Using autolayout how can I do animation like ease in, ease out. Should I switch to core-animation for this. 
For animation using constraints I understood from this link [How do I animate constraint changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622424/how-do-i-animate-constraint-changes)

But they are not talking about animating like this.[image]

How would I do animation like this, or in a bezier path using bezier function which would look good in all iOS sizes of screens . I searched a lot but I am missing this answer for a long time. A standard practise of doing ease in ease out or along a bezier path using **autolayout** . I understand there is a workaround but again asking for the standard practise?

Comment: At the end you end up looking into UIVIew animation with autolayout. Autolayout alone doesnt do animation. It does with the help of UIView animation. MOst of the methods you mentioned can be done using UIView animation.

Comment: Yes, if I am not using autolayout, I would consider the frame as my key. I would do changes in it, as I have precise control over it. But autolayout takes away the frame from you as a developer and now I want to animate the UIView from this frame to that frame in a bezier path with ease in ease out animation. How would I achieve that?

Comment: what do you mean by 'autolayout takes away the frame from you' ?

Comment: You don't supply the frame or even think in terms of frames, but the autolayout engine provides it for you

Comment: still exploring the area, but you can create custom animation curves with `[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithControlPoints:::]`. Then use this with a `CABasicAnimation animation; animation.timingFunction = [the thing above]`