# Should I call layoutIfNeeded inside viewDidLayoutSubviews()

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, layout, constraints

I am changing some constraints and hiding some elements on a certain VC depending on what device the user is using.

Like this:

```
   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        if Iphone6 == true {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.someConst.constant = 70
            self.anotherConst.constant = 67
            self.someButton.hidden = true
            self.someView.hidden = true
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }   
   }
```

Now I wonder if I need to call `layoutIfNeeded()` twice in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` ?

I do know that you have to call layoutIfNeeded() twice if you are using `animateWithDuration` when changing constraints but this it also apply to viewDidLayoutSubviews?

Thanks,

Comment: I would put your `if`statement in `viewdidload` instead of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: @SeNeO how come? I thought that you should not modify your constraints / elements in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of `layoutIfNeeded()` is to force a synchronous (essentially "immediate") redraw of a view and its subviews. When dealing with animations, Apple considers it best practice to call `layoutIfNeeded()` prior to the animation block to ensure pending layout operations have fully completed. This prepares the views for the operations to determine and set their new layouts. `layoutIfNeeded()` is then called a second time within the animation block to ensure the animated changes to the layout are also completed.

Apple's documentation for `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` expresses that *this method being called does not indicate that the individual layouts of the view'€™s subviews have been adjusted*. So when you start to check the device being used and adjust the layout accordingly, there's no guarantee all prior layout operations have completed successfully. For that reason, **it's a good idea for you to continue to call `layoutIfNeeded()` twice**. Once to make sure any previous layout operations are wrapped up and once again to enact the layout changes you've made based on the device type.

**Sources:**

[How do I animate constraint changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12664093/6200684)

[setNeedsLayout vs layoutIfNeeded Explained](https://web.archive.org/web/20161205005550/http://www.iosinsight.com/setneedslayout-vs-layoutifneeded-explained/)

[viewDidLayoutSubviews Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews)