# Temporarily disable/remove constraints while animating UI elements

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, uikit, nslayoutconstraint

I've nicely setup my UI inside a storyboard controller. Running the app, everything looks & works great inside the iPhone 5S simulator. More importantly, all the UI elements that have their own IBOutlet (for animation purposes) to the code behave as programmed: moving as intended when methods animate these UI elements when needed.

However, I added constraints by clicking the controller inside the storyboard --> Editor --> Resolve Auto Layout Issues --> Add Missing Constraints. After that, animations stop working because the constraints are keeping them in place.

Is there some sort of command/code to "pause/stop/remove/disable" the constraints during animation & then add them back, when animations are finished, without having to do add constraints back manually?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're using Autolayout, you should not be trying to move views by changing their frames. You should be animating changes to the constraints, instead.

See this StackOverflow answer for hints:

[How do I animate constraint changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622424/how-do-i-animate-constraint-changes)

Comment: Alright. So disabling constraints is not possible. If animation can now only occur from manipulating the actual constraints then that requires a new approach to animating. Thanks for the link: that should get me started.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use Animation and Autolayout together is by creating IBOutlet of the UI Elements(UILabel, UIButton etc.).

You can change their *constant* value according to your animation requirements.

Comment: The 'constant' is an important piece of the puzzle.