# Why UIView.animate(withDuration has not effect?

Tags: ios, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

I try to perform a layout update, with following lines, but animation is prompt, there is no delay. Any idea why? Using 8.0 Xcode.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 12.0, animations: {

    self.yellowLineLeadingConstraint.isActive = false
    self.yellowLineTrailingConstraint.isActive = false

    self.yellowLineLeadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.yellowLine, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: b, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    self.yellowLineTrailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.yellowLine, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: b, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

    self.view.addConstraints([self.yellowLineLeadingConstraint, self.yellowLineTrailingConstraint])

    self.yellowLineLeadingConstraint.isActive = true
    self.yellowLineTrailingConstraint.isActive = true
})
```

Comment: Try adding self.view.layoutIfNeeded

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to animate layout constraints is to change them beforehand, and call `layoutIfNeeded` in your animation block (this tells the view to actually update its layout). So your code would look like this:

```
self.yellowLineLeadingConstraint.isActive = false
self.yellowLineTrailingConstraint.isActive = false

self.yellowLineLeadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.yellowLine, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: b, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
self.yellowLineTrailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.yellowLine, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: b, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

self.view.addConstraints([self.yellowLineLeadingConstraint, self.yellowLineTrailingConstraint])

self.yellowLineLeadingConstraint.isActive = true
self.yellowLineTrailingConstraint.isActive = true

UIView.animate(withDuration: 12.0, animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You aren't changing any "animatable" attributes. I see you are updating your constraint attribute, but it's not one of these [Animatable Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AnimatableProperties/AnimatableProperties.html)

Comment: This is not true, you can animate constraint changes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622424/how-do-i-animate-constraint-changes