# UIView constraints won't animate if layoutIfNeeded() is called

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, animation, uiview

I'm trying to animate a view that is constrained (`iconVerticalConstraint`) to be at center Y (`+100`) of a superview, specifically reaching its right (`0`) position after an animation.
Here's my code:

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, animations: {

    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations:{
        self.iconVerticalConstraint.constant -= 20
    })

    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.25, relativeDuration: 0.75, animations:{
        self.iconVerticalConstraint.constant -= 80
    })
})
```

I tried following [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622424) but that didn't help, because in my case my view contains more subviews, intrinsically linked, and putting `layoutIfNeeded()` in my animation block would animate the **whole** view, and not just that constraint. Otherwise this approach does no animation at all.

Comment: Note that if I move the `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` inside the `animateKeyframes` block, the animation occurs, but it animates all of the view (just like it should, in my opinion) and not only the constraint, as written in the first comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I animate constraint changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622424/how-do-i-animate-constraint-changes)

Comment: Edited to explain the difference with the possible duplicate.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Could the downvoter explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of time spent to understand the basic mechanism, I can provide my own answer, for all of you who will find themselves in my situation.

`layoutIfNeeded()` tells to the view to adjust position of *all of its subviews*.
`animate` or `animateKeyframes` or every other alternative you're using, instead, tells to the view to perform any of the instructions inside the *animation block* in the way you specify in the `animate` function (by default, with a `options: .easeInOut`)

Back to the question: the problem was in the fact that `animate` and `layoutIfNeeded` are called ***asynchronously*** so that, in fact, every instruction inside the animation block was executed just before the `layoutIfNeeded` instruction, making it useless. The solution isn't putting the `layoutIfNeeded` instruction inside the animation block, as suggested by SeanLintern88 because in this way we would tell the view to ***adjust the position of its subviews according to the animation options***. That's the key point.

The answer is somewhat simple. Move the animation part on the **subview itself**, specifically in a point when you know that the **superview** has already been "autolayouted" (e.g. `viewDidAppear`), so that the constraint is already defined and executed, and you can now change it. In that point, code should look like this:

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, animations: {

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations:{
        self.iconVerticalConstraint.constant -= 20
    })

    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.25, relativeDuration: 0.75, animations:{
        self.iconVerticalConstraint.constant -= 80
    })
})
```

Because you **want** to animate the autolayout.

Another option (for instance, if you haven't/don't want to create a class for your subview) is to change ***bounds/center*** of the subview itself in the `viewDidAppear` function of the parent view. This is because, if you are in the parent view, you know that at that point auto layout has already been *registered* but not executed, in the more precise sense that bounds and center have been already changed according to the auto layout.

If you then change them, you'll obtain your desired animation (but *remember*: auto layout is still on, so you must change the constraints in a way that reflects the final position of your animation; if you wish, you can do that in the `completion` part of `animate` function).

Answer (score 5):

changing constraints such as

```
self.iconVerticalConstraint.constant -= 20
```

should be OUTSIDE the animation block and inside you just call

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

I think because you are trying to do 2, and calling

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

They all happen once, consider changing to:

```
    self.iconVerticalConstraint.constant -= 20

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { (finished) in
     
        self.iconVerticalConstraint.constant -= 80

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

Edit: Explanation

When you change a constraint, the view will not update until the next layout cycle, usually when you exit your current scope. So when you want to animate a constraint, you change the constant BEFORE the animation block, then inside the animation block you call `layoutIfNeeded()` This tells it to animate the now forced layout cycle.

Now in your example, you where calling `layoutIfNeeded()` which would do nothing at that point, then changing 2 constants, without telling the layout to animate, so when the scope exited, the UI would layout without animation.

In your case you want to chain the changing of 2 constants, but you dont have a way of changing the second constant `(80)` after the first animation completes, and if you set both, both constants will be adjusted on the FIRST `layoutIfNeeded()` hence, the chaining of animations, which will still work with your other animations that you omitted, just add then in the first animation block if they are in the first keyframe and the second if they were in the second.

Final Edit:

Also you can change your `layoutIfNeeded()` currently applied to self.view to actually on the views it affects, in this case `iconVerticalConstraint` if it was a view that is attached to another view say a top attached to a view bottom, if you wanna animate, you must call `layoutIfNeeded()` on each view it affects