# io swift Animation: alpha and constraint

Tags: ios, swift, animation

This is my code, and the skip button animation does not work. It just disappear immediately.
It just disappear

```
skipButtonBottomConstraint.constant = -40

 UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {

                self.titleLabel.alpha = 0
                self.skipButton.alpha = 0
                self.pageControl.alpha = 0


                self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    })
```

could you explain me the reason?

Comment: Show all other operations/codes you have set around this function. May you have set something that effect on animation

Comment: Call `layoutIfNeeded` instead of `setNeedsLayout`

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you! It's the correct answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I animate constraint changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622424/how-do-i-animate-constraint-changes)

Comment: What your main design goal? Can you explain it? Also what you expected from this block? It's just disappears and not anything else.

Comment: Also you should call it before animation block to make sure all pending operation are completed

Answer (score 2):

I think Paul is right, and you should be calling `layoutIfNeeded()` inside the animation block, not `setNeedsLayout()`

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you are calling `layoutIfNeeded` after you `setNeedsLayout`

Also as Apple recommends - call it once before the animation block to ensure that all pending layout operations have been completed.

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
self.skipButtonBottomConstraint.constant = -40
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {    
        self.titleLabel.alpha = 0
        self.skipButton.alpha = 0
        self.pageControl.alpha = 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

Comment: nope.... don't work, it still disappear suddenly, I don't know if it's because it moves immediately out of screen or because of the alpha

Comment: @TheMiotz According to code you have shown here, this answer is correct and it should work

Comment: You should definitely adjust the constraint outside the animation block