# CosmicMind Material TextField : Adjust TextField position when it becomes first responder

Tags: ios, uitextfield, material-design, cosmicmind

I have a view and I have two Material Textfields in it. The problem is when I have to show detail Message or when the I click on text field the placeholder moves up. So if the space between fields is less then the animated placeholder text gets overlapped with above text field.

So far I have kept enough space between fields to rid of this issue but it does not look good moreover, in Android when the user clicks on the textfield and its animated text shows the textfield automatically moves some points down or up to cater the inner spacing issue.

Default View with [image: without detail message and placeholder]

[image: placeholder and error message]

Comment: You can adjust `placeholderVerticalOffset` on the texfields

Comment: I know that but I want it to animate. placeholderVerticalOffset will have an impact on the distance between placeholder and TextField when animated

Comment: You want to move the `textField` down with animation when it is first responder or has text?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov when it becomes first responder. Main purpose is to accommodate the "animated PlaceHolder". Otherwise it overlaps with other text fields

Comment: How do you layout the textFields? Probably using autolayout? Can you share code?

Comment: I am using storyboard. So the constraints are set on storyboard. Basically Trailing left, right, Top space and then Fixed Height

Comment: So your password field has top constraint from username field. You can bind that constraint to the file via `@IBOOutlet`, update the `constraint.constant` and animate it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622424/how-do-i-animate-constraint-changes).

Comment: BTW, I would avoid giving fixed height constraint to the textFields as it creates unnecessary space between `placeholderLabel` and `textField` itself.

Comment: yes I have that in mind and I was also thinking about that. But I thought there might be other ways as well.