# How to animate the view to the center of X and Y?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I have an ImageView that have centerX and centerY constraint to the `Helper Header View` like the image below

[image]

I want to animate that logo imageView to be located at the center of the screen like image below:
[image]

I have tried some code, but it doesn't work, to be honest I am not sure with this code below, here is what I try. maybe you have better approach. here is what I tried

first I try to give identifier to both constraint :
[image]
[image]

and then I remove the constraint and make a new one like the code below:

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.1, delay: 0.5, usingSpringWithDamping:  0.4, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, animations: {

            // remove the initial constraint
            self.mainLogoCenterXConstraint.isActive = false
            self.mainLogoCenterYConstraint.isActive = false

            // create new constraint
            let newMainLogoCenterXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
                item: self.mainLogoImageView,
                attribute: .centerX,
                relatedBy: .equal,
                toItem: self.view,
                attribute: .centerY,
                multiplier: 1.0,
                constant: 0)
            newMainLogoCenterXConstraint.identifier = "mainLogoCenterXConstraint"
            newMainLogoCenterXConstraint.isActive = true

            let newMainLogoCenterYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
                item: self.mainLogoImageView,
                attribute: .centerY,
                relatedBy: .equal,
                toItem: self.view,
                attribute: .centerY,
                multiplier: 1.0,
                constant: 0)
            newMainLogoCenterYConstraint.identifier = "mainLogoCenterYConstraint"
            newMainLogoCenterYConstraint.isActive = true


            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }, completion: nil)
```

but it crash and give error:

> 'NSInvalidLayoutConstraintException', reason: 'Constraint improperly
>   relates anchors of incompatible types:

maybe you have better way to achieve this....

Comment: **DO NOT** change constraints just for animation! Animate using [.transform property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622459-transform): first set offset, than animate to `.identity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in creating the first constraint relating `self.mainLogoImageView.centerX` to `self.view.centerY` - change the second one to `self.view.centerX`. You cannot bind x-axis anchor to y-axis anchor.

Moreover, make sure you animate it properly, check my answer on how to do that with autolayout [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48825477/2912282).

In your case:

```
// remove the initial constraint
self.mainLogoCenterXConstraint.isActive = false
self.mainLogoCenterYConstraint.isActive = false

// create new constraint
let newMainLogoCenterXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: self.mainLogoImageView,
            attribute: .centerX,
            relatedBy: .equal,
            toItem: self.view,
            attribute: .centerX,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0)
newMainLogoCenterXConstraint.identifier = "mainLogoCenterXConstraint"
newMainLogoCenterXConstraint.isActive = true

let newMainLogoCenterYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: self.mainLogoImageView,
            attribute: .centerY,
            relatedBy: .equal,
            toItem: self.view,
            attribute: .centerY,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0)
newMainLogoCenterYConstraint.identifier = "mainLogoCenterYConstraint"
newMainLogoCenterYConstraint.isActive = true

self.view.setNeedsLayout()

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.1, delay: 0.5, usingSpringWithDamping:  0.4, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, animations: {

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

}, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
     // create new constraint
        let newMainLogoCenterXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: self.mainLogoImageView,
            attribute: .centerX,
            relatedBy: .equal,
            toItem: self.view,
            attribute: .centerY,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0)
```

you give center X,y which are in Compatible types ,    but both should  be centerX

Also this isn't sufficient to show the image at center of view , as it's a subview of helperView , so you need to set

```
 self.helperView.clipsToBounds = false // if it's true
```