# Animate NSLayoutConstraint created programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nslayoutconstraint, uiviewanimation

Something special has to be done to animate a constraint instantiated programmatically?

I instantiate a constraint programmatically as a lazy variable:

```
private lazy var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
    let constraint = view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: otherView.topAnchor, constant: otherView)
    return constraint
}()
```

Then, I animate a change in the constant of this constraint:

```
topConstraint.constant = newValue
view.setNeedsLayout()
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

It is not working... I also have tried putting the constant setting into the block:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
    self.topConstraint.constant = newValue
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

But I achieved nothing at all, I've tried almost all the combinations. The constraint constant is properly changed, but always without animation.

PD: I also gave a shot to `UIViewPropertyAnimator`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I animate constraint changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622424/how-do-i-animate-constraint-changes)

Comment: No, this question asks if there is something special to do when the constraint is created by code... No storyboard.

Comment: First, you set `constant: otherView` ... that should be a `CGFloat`, not a reference to a view. Second, are you ever setting `topConstraint.isActive = true`?

Answer (score 1):

No need for `setNeedsLayout()`.

```
self.topConstraint.constant = 0.0
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {[weak self] in
    self?.topConstraint.constant = 10.0 
    self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: I tried this, it's not working in this scenario neither.

Comment: Try setting some hardcode values first and check if is working. Updated the answer. See if it works now.

Comment: No, I tried all this things that should work... But the constraint change can't be animated

Comment: Inside the handler (selector) of the pan gesture recognizer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199289/discussion-between-sergio-and-pgdev).