# UItextView iOS 7 issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, ios7

I have come to an issue with iOS 7 that I dont know how to solve. I have multiple UItextviews that present a keyboard on touch. For iOS 6 the view scrolls up and the keyboard is shown underneath, but when i run it on iOS 7 the view gets pushed underneath the keyboard. I cant figure out why the view is getting pushed down in iOS 7. i dont have any code that handles iOS 7 different.

UITextView

[image: UITextView]

iOS 6

[image: iOS 6]

i OS 7

[image: iOS 7]

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using to handle the keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431684/uitextview-cursor-below-frame-when-changing-frame/18585788#18585788) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18969421/983912).

You should set `contentInset` `bottom` to the keyboard's height and then add some code to handle the view that is below the keyboard to be scrolled to visible.