# Chaos in debugger during to get keyboard rect

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When the keyboard rectangle appears, I would like to move my views. I worked from the [best answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169702/how-to-resize-uitextview-on-ios-when-a-keyboard-appears) to attempt to implement this in Swift.

When the program tries to get the `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` value it found `nil`. But if I cast this value to `NSValue` it HAS the value of `NSRect` type. If I try to cast it to `NSRect` I get an error "Undeclared type". If I cast it to `CGREct` I get `nil`. What's going on here?

[image]

Comment: You have to call the `CGRectValue` function on the `NSValue` object to get the `CGRect`.

Comment: Please insert your code as text.

Comment: @rmaddy, That works for me! Thank you!